# Ошибка mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите решить проблему выдает такую ошибку

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in /home/gtiradio/domains/gtiradio.ru/admin/reg/index.php on line
>   373

Указывает на:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result_1) == 0) { ... }
```

Что не так?

Comment: запрос отвалился с ошибкой 

[deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: фишка в том что буквально 5 дней назад работало все отлично я ничего не менял

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, если вы хотите пожаловаться то, что некоторое время назад ошибки не было (а не причины ее возникновения), то вам [сюда](http://vpustotu.ru/), [сюда](http://vk.com/aboutgrouptherapy) или [сюда](http://www.russianpost.ru/). Если же вы все-таки заинтересованы в разворачивании клубка ошибки назад, прислушайтесь к комментарию от @Андрей Таланин. Я же предполагаю, что в той или иной части нарушена схема БД.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А у вас в $result_1 булев тип, об этом и говорится в ошибке. Посмотрите, где и как эта переменная получает логическое значение, [не должно быть такого](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

Comment: а почему работало буквально 5 дней назад, а щас перестало видите ли...

Comment: андрей спачибо, решил проблему.

Answer (score -3):

Скорее всего результатом выполнения запроса является ошибка. Попробуйте посмотреть результат функции [mysql_error()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-error.php)

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.