# mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli_result), boolean given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-faq, php-faq

Я пытаюсь получить данные из таблицы MySQL, но вылезает одна из этих ошибок:

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

или

> mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Вот мой код:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE $username");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['FirstName'];
}
```

<sub>[Оригинальный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973202/293099).</sub>

Comment: Вокруг $username в запросе кавычек не хватает.

Comment: @Denis, кавычки там не спасут

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973202/5000805

Answer (score 77):

### Как избежать такой ошибки

Эта ошибка - вторичная. И в правильно спроектированном приложении возникать в принципе не должна.

Она лишь сигнализирует о том, что **предыдущая** функция, которая выполняла SQL запрос, окончилась неудачей, но при этом о причине неудачи никакой информации не несёт.

Чтобы таких ошибок в коде не возникало, необходимо получить сообщение об ошибке из базы данных. Но делать это надо с умом, а не так, как советуют неспециалисты, десятилетиями переписывая друг у друга один и тот же код, не понимая его смысла и не сталкиваясь с результатами его работы ([весьма плачевными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/422994/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0/)) на практике.

## Mysqli

Чтобы транслировать ошибки базы данных в ошибки РНР, в mysqli не нужно проверять результат каждой функции. Вместо этого достаточно перед коннектом написать вот такую строчку:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

и тогда все ошибки БД будут порождать исключения, которые по умолчанию становятся фатальными ошибками РНР, а значит при ошибке запроса программист будет немедленно проинформирован **точно так же**, как о любых других возникающих в работе скрипта ошибках. А до ошибки "expects parameter" дело уже не дойдет.

#### mysql_query

Внимание! **Этой функции уже много лет не существует в языке**. И это значит что ваш код настолько древний, что он не будет работать на большинстве хостингов. Но если все же приходится копаться в этом экскременте мамонта, то взывая функцию `mysql_query()`, необходимо всегда проверять результат её работы и выбрасывать ошибку РНР с реальным сообщением об ошибке от БД:

```
$sql = "SELECT ...";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ". $sql);
```

## Как вообще увидеть сообщение об ошибке

Предыдущие рекомендации показывают, как в принципе заставить БД сообщать об ошибках. Но чтобы увидеть ошибку, надо также соответствующим образом настроить РНР

- В локальном/тестовом окружении

  - `error_reporting` всегда в значении `E_ALL`;
  - `log_errors` в значении 1 (это бывает полезно)
  - `display_errors` в значении to 1
- На боевом сервере

  - `error_reporting` всегда в значении `E_ALL`;
  - `log_errors` установить в 1
  - `display_errors` установить в 0

Таким образом на локальном сервере ошибки будут отображаться на экране, а на боевом - писаться в лог ошибок, где их можно будет посмотреть

## Что нельзя делать при обработке ошибок

Никаких `echo` и `die()`. Ошибки базы данных должны всегда транслироваться в ошибки РНР и выводиться туда, куда выводятся все остальные. Если на сайте запрещен вывод ошибок в браузер, то ошибки БД не должны быть исключением из этого правила.

## Как исправить ошибку

**Надо прочитать сообщение об ошибке.**

Это звучит банальностью, но на удивление никто из неспециалистов раздающих советы **никогда этого не упоминает!** При том что прочтение текста ошибки помогает в сто раз лучше шаманских телодвижений типа "пересчитайте все кавычки":

Во-первых, mysql сразу скажет, **в чем суть ошибки**. Если в базе нет таблицы, к которой мы обращаемся, или сервер весь целиком упал, то пересчитывать кавычки *бесполезно*.
Во-вторых, если ошибка все-таки в синтаксисе, то mysql **точно укажет место где её искать** - она процитирует кусок запроса, начинающийся сразу за ошибкой.

## Как раз и навсегда избавиться от ошибок синтаксиса, вызванных данными

Если проблема всё-таки в синтаксисе, и при этом вызвана переданными в запрос данными, то Самой Дурацкой Идеей будет "экранировать ваши значения с помощью `mysql_real_escape_string()`". И уж тем более глупостью будет применять эту функцию для защиты от SQL инъекций. Она не для этого предназначена.

Для того, чтобы навсегда избавиться от любых проблем, связанных с передаваемыми в запрос переменными, **необходимо перестать вставлять их в строку запроса напрямую.** А делать это **только через посредника**, называемого **"плейсхолдер"**.

Таким образом, для данного запроса код с использованием mysqli будет таким

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['FirstName'];
}
```

Да, получилось длинновато. Поэтому (и по многим другим причинам) вмето mysqli рекомендуется использовать PDO:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute([$username]);
while($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    echo $row['FirstName'];
}
```

Answer (score 40):

## Откуда берётся ошибка

Эта ошибка возникает, если запрос не может быть выполнен. Функции, которые могут к ней привести:

- `mysql_fetch_array`/`mysqli_fetch_array()`
- `mysql_fetch_assoc()`/`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`
- `mysql_num_rows()`/`mysqli_num_rows()`

Если с запросом всё в порядке, и просто результат его выполнения пустой, то ошибка не возникает. К ошибке приводит только неверный синтаксис SQL.

## Как найти источник ошибки

- Убедитесь, что на сервере, на котором вы ведёте разработку, включено отображение всех ошибок. Вы можете включить его из PHP, выполнив [`error_reporting(-1);`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.error-reporting.php) (можно разместить этот код в конфигурационном файле вашего сайта, например). Если при попытке выполнения запроса будут обнаружены ошибки в синтаксисе, то они будут отображены.
- Используйте [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-error.php). Эта функция вернёт строку с текстом ошибки, если таковая возникла при выполнении последнего запроса.

  Например:

  ```
  mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Ошибка подключения");
  mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("Ошибка выбора БД");

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  if ($result === false) {
      echo mysql_error();
  }
  ```
- Выполните ваш запрос в командной строке MySQL или из инструмента вроде [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php). Если в запросе есть синтаксическая ошибка, то она будет отображена.
- Убедитесь, что в запросе верно расставлены кавычки. Это частая причина синтаксических ошибок.
- Убедитесь, что вы экранируете ваши значения. Если в строке присутствует кавычка, это может привести к ошибке (а также сделать ваш код уязвимым к SQL-инъекциям). Используйте для этого [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).
- Убедитесь, что вы не используете одновременно функции `mysqli_*` и `mysql_*`. Их использование нельзя смешивать. (Если вы не знаете, что выбрать, отдайте предпочтение `mysqli_*`.)

## Советы

Не используйте функции `mysql_*` в новом коде. Разработчики PHP больше не поддерживают и не развивают их, они отмечены как устаревшие, и в будущих версиях будут удалены. Ознакомьтесь с понятием [prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) и переходите на использование [PDO](http://php.net/ru/pdo) (PHP Data Objects) или [MySQLi](http://php.net/ru/mysqli) (MySQL improved). Это избавит вас от проблем с экранированием значений и убережёт от SQL-инъекций.

И MySQLi, и PDO поддерживают режим, в котором при ошибках выбрасываются исключения. В новом коде следует использовать этот подход, потому что он помогает обрабатывать ошибки в одном месте, а не размазывать проверки по всему коду, и позволяет обработке ошибок не зависеть от внешних условий (от конфигурации).

[Сравнение возможностей PDO и MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). Если вкратце, то PDO — это общий слой над базами данных, который позволяет относительно легко переключать СУБД; а MySQLi даёт доступ к некоторым дополнительным возможностям СУБД MySQL.

<sub>Преимущественно перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11674313).</sub>