# Ошибка: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysql

Почему выскакивает такая ошибка?

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in Z:\home\Anastasiya\www\search.php on line 22

Хочу сделать поиск по сайту, с помощью БД.
Создала БД "anastasiya" (в которой и буду совершать поиск) с таблицей "content".

Вот код:

```
    $areaywords = explode(" ", $words);
    print_r($areaywords);
    foreach ($areaywords as $key => $value){
        if (isset($areaywords[$key - 1]))
        $query_search .= ' OR ';
        $query_search .='`title` LIKE "%'.$value.'%" OR `text_article` LIKE "%'.$value.'%"';
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE $query_search";
    echo $query;
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "anastasiya");
    $result_set = $mysqli->query($query);
    $mysqli -> close();

    $i = 0;
    while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()){
        $results[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }
    return $results;

}
if (isset ($_POST['bcearch'])){
    $words = $_POST['words'];
    $results = search($words);
}
```

Ругается на строку:

```
while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()){
```

Comment: Интерпретатор PHP недвусмысленно дает вам понять, что функция `$result_set->fetch_assoc` должна вызываться без параметров.

Comment: @Anastasiya, `а зачем вы закрыли подключение к базе до выборки результатов из запроса?` вы на этот мой вопрос ноль внимания обратили.

Comment: Вы не правы, я обратила внимание и приняла меры

Comment: $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "anastasiya");
  $result_set = $mysqli->query($query);
  var_dump($result_set);exit;
  
  if ($mysqli->connect_errno) { die('Ошибка соединения: ' . $mysqli->connect_error); } else{echo 'Connect true';}
  $i = 0;
  while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()){
   $results[$i] = $row;
   $i++;
  }
  $mysqli -> close();
  
  return $results;

Comment: Но это ничего не дало.

Comment: Теперь этот постоянно меняющийся вопрос является дубликатом http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole

Comment: Причем здесь одно к другому???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Проверьте выполняется ли конечный запрос $query(который выводится после строки `echo $query;`) через консоль базы данных.
2. Проверьте доступ к бд:

   if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
      die('Ошибка соединения: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }else{echo 'Connect true';}
3. выполните `var_dump($result_set);` что показывает выполнение?

P.S.: зачастую проблема либо в некорректном запросе либо в настройке доступа к бд.

Comment: echo $query; - выполняется отлично. Может что-то и правда с доступом к БД. Но как это отследить? Выполнила var_dump($result_set); - вывело bool(false)

Comment: Показывает "Connect true".

Comment: У меня есть БД "anastasiya" в ней создана таблица "content". А в таблице такие поля "id", "title" и "text_article". В таблице я создала 2 строки 1." title" - Ландшафтный дизайн; "text_article" -Занимаясь процессом обустройства альпинария, буква...

Comment: Вот все что у меня выводится Array ( [0] => Ландшафтный [1] => дизайн ) SELECT * FROM content WHERE `title` LIKE "%Ландшафтный%" OR `text_article` LIKE "%Ландшафтный%" OR `title` LIKE "%дизайн%" OR `text_article` LIKE "%дизайн%"
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in Z:\home\Anastasiya\www\search.php on line 22

Comment: Вот мой код  http://pastebin.com/ZjJDc44C

Comment: На данный момент ошибки нету, но результат поиска не выводит. Вот что выводит Array ( [0] => Ландшафтный [1] => дизайн [2] => ) SELECT * FROM contentConnect true

Comment: @Anastasiya, пример самого просто вывода в Вашем случае [http://pastebin.com/hB5xzdji](http://pastebin.com/hB5xzdji) строки 24-34. Попробуйте пример и напишите получилось ли вывести данные?

Comment: Спасибо. Что-то вывелось, только иероглифами. Вот: Array ( [0] => Ландшафтный [1] => дизайн ) SELECT * FROM contentConnect trueВсего найдено2 строк: 
id =1 title =Р›Р°РЅРґС€Р°С„С‚РЅС‹Р№ РґРёР·Р°Р№РЅ text_article =Р—Р°РЅРёРјР°СЏСЃСЊ РїСЂРѕС†РµСЃСЃРѕРј РѕР±СѓСЃС‚СЂРѕР№СЃС‚РІР° Р°Р»СЊРїРёРЅР°СЂРёСЏ, Р±СѓРєРІР°Р»СЊРЅРѕ ЋС‚ С‡СѓРґРµСЃРЅРѕ РїРѕРґРѕР

Comment: Пробовала поменять кодировку на UTF-8 без ВОМ, не помогло.

Comment: Вот что получилось: Array ( [0] => Ландшафтный [1] => дизайн ) SELECT * FROM contentConnect trueР’СЃРµРіРѕ РЅР°Р№РґРµРЅРѕ СЃС‚СЂРѕРє: 

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in Z:\home\Anastasiya\www\search.php on line 29

Answer (score 0):

У метода fetch_assoc() в скобочках ничего быть не должно.

```
while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()){
```

Comment: Дело в том что когда я пишу так как вы сказали. У меня появляется ошибка "Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in"

Comment: @Anastasiya, а зачем вы закрыли подключение к базе до выборки результатов из запроса?

Comment: @AndrewGodin, почему там ни чего не должно быть? Вот тут http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php явно написано `array mysqli_fetch_assoc ( mysqli_result $result )`?

Comment: Да. Спасибо. Это понятно. Только вот почему оно все равно не работает.

Comment: @Anastasiya, кто кроме вас знает это? :) Лучше, наверное, вам зайти в правку вопроса и дополнить его **текущим вариантом вашего кода** и **текущей ошибкой**. А то в ответах и комментариях к ним много уже написано всего, что и не поймешь текущее состояние.

Answer (score -1):

Как уже ответил Dmitriy Simushev, ответ на вопрос написан в Warning. Если перевести, то получится Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_assoc() ожидает только 0 параметров, дан 1. Об mysqli_fetch_assoc можно почитать тут http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Вместо

```
$i = 0;
    while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc($result_set)){
        $results[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }
```

Попробуйте так

```
while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) {
        $results[] = array [$row['название_первого_поля'], $row['название_второго_поля'], и т.д.]
    }
```

И не стесняйтесь пользоваться https://translate.google.com/, а лучше, учите английский.

Comment: Скорее всего не удалось соединиться с БД. Попробуйте после `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "anastasiya"); `поставить проверку `if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Соединение не удалось: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}`

Comment: Я написала if ($mysqli->connect_errno) { die('Ошибка соединения: ' . $mysqli->connect_error); } else{echo 'Connect true';}
  И мне вывело -"Connect true"

Comment: Хорошо, попробуйте после `$result_set = $mysqli->query($query);` поставить `var_dump($result_set);exit;` Если в `$result_set` что-то будет, тогда попробуйте `$mysqli -> close();`  перенести ниже и поставить перед `return $results;`

Comment: Что нужно написать после $result_set = $mysqli->query($query);?

Comment: var_dump($result_set);exit;

Comment: Теперь оно не ругается. Но и не выдает результат((

Comment: Вот что пишет Array ( [0] => Ландшафтный [1] => дизайн ) SELECT * FROM content WHERE `title` LIKE "%Ландшафтный%" OR `text_article` LIKE "%Ландшафтный%" OR `title` LIKE "%дизайн%" OR `text_article` LIKE "%дизайн%"bool(false)

Comment: видите, в конце написано bool(false), это значит, что что-то не срабатывает в запросе. Для SELECT должен возвращаться объект. Очень может быть что не найдено результата по такому запросу. Удалите var_dump($result_set);exit; и попробуйте $query = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE $query_search"; заменить на $query = "SELECT * FROM content. Если заработает, то или ошибка в запросе или нет искомого результата в таблице

Comment: Неа, ничего не получилось( Вот что пишет Array ( [0] => Ландшафтный [1] => дизайн ) SELECT * FROM contentobject(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(2) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Вы не удалили строчку  var_dump($result_set);exit; Удалите и попробуйте

Comment: Удалила. Спасибо, ошибки нету пишет tConnect true. Но результат поиска не выводит. Вот что выводит Array ( [0] => Ландшафтный [1] => дизайн [2] => ) SELECT * FROM contentConnect true