# Ошибка fetch_assoc()

Tags: php

Не могу понять, почему появляется ошибка в функции

```
function close_orders($asc_price, $bid_price, $name_prod)
{
    $Orders = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->query("SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE 'price' >= $asc_price AND 'price' <= $bid_price AND 'name_prod' = $name_prod ORDER BY 'user_id' ASC" );
    $Orders_users=array();
    while ($row = $Orders->fetch_assoc()) {
        $Orders_users[]=$row;
    }
```

Ошибка

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc()

Comment: а такой метод вообще есть? вижу функцию `mysql_fetch_assoc` https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Ошибку надо публиковать __целиком__, здесь нет телепатов. `Call to a member function fetch_assoc() __on boolean__`?

Comment: @Lexx918 по Вашей ссылке смотрите примеры->Объектно-ориентированный стиль

Comment: сделайте `echo $GLOBALS['mysqli']->error;` и `var_dump($Orders);`, скорее всего ошибка при выполнении запроса

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456296/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-call-to-a-member-function-fetch-assoc-on-a-non-object-in

Comment: В Вашем запросе колонки таблицы обрамлены в прямые кавычки, а должны быть в обратные, а также значения лучше обрамлять в прямые кавычки