# На какую функцию нужно поменять mysql_result, что бы код заработал?

Tags: php, mysql

Учусь PHP по книжке Никсона и во время набора кода с неё IDE начал мне подсвечивать некоторые функции как устаревшие и я решил постараться переработать код на более актуальной, но с проблемой которая видна на скриншоте мне к сожалению справиться не удалось.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Для получения $result Вы используете **mysqli**_query, а для получения результата **mysql**_result - это уже надо починить на mysqli
2) Теперь данные из базы надо получать не напрямую из mysqli_result - такой функции нет, а например так: mysqli_fetch_row ( $result ). Это вернет ассоциативный массив и вот из него уже данные и получать