# Узнать общую сумму определенных товаров

Tags: php, mysql

При добавлении товара в корзину, в базе данных, в таблицу `cart` добавляется запись: id - AUTO_INCREMENT, **user** - id пользователя который добавил товар, **tov** - id самого товара.

Записи о товарах хранятся в таблице `tov` , запись о сумме товара в ячейке **cena** .

Вопрос, как подсчитать общую сумму товаров которые пользователь добавил в корзину?

Comment: покажите структуру таблицы, запрос который вы пробовали. если можно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sum(cena)
from cart 
inner join tov on tov.id = cart.tov
where cart.user = 10
```

Comment: не подскажете в чем ошибка? что-то не так наверное я сделал `$sqlStr = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT sum(cena) FROM cart inner join tovar on tov.id = cart.tov where cart.user = '1'"));
`

Comment: @Денис что за ошибку дает? логи покажите

Comment: вообще не чего не выводит.. хотя показ ошибок включен

Comment: @Денис интересно. покажите `var_dump($sqlStr)` может там что то есть. И включите логи php

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: @Денис: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/423439/178576