# Как правильно работать с WHERE в MySql

Tags: php, mysqli

Когда произвожу запрос к базе вытащить все поля где id = 1 всё нормально работает, но когда меняю например на "foreign" (в этом столбце тоже есть 1)
Выдаёт ошибку:

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given ....

Вот код

```
<?php
$foreign = 1;
$query  = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE foreign = {$foreign}";
$time_set = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($time_set)){
 echo $row['message'];  
}
```

С этим же кодом но со столбцом id,всё прекрасно работ:

```
<?php
$foreign = 1;
$query  = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id = {$foreign}";
$time_set = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($time_set)){
 echo $row['message'];  
}
```

В чём ошибка?

Comment: А где connection собственно?

Comment: у меня проблему не с соединением собственно,а с выборкой,так как если бы были проблемы с конекшеном то при использовании второго кода тоже была бы ошиба....Логично?

Comment: @Павел слово `foreign` зарезервировано в SQL, столбец с таким именем стоит заключать в обратные апострофы. Кроме того http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole

Comment: @Mike Спасибо огромное