# Ошибка в mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql

При выполнении пост запроса выскакивает ошибка:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   object given in /home/u249644105/public_html/get.php on line 12

Вот код:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        //Getting values 
                $imei = $_POST['imei'];

$sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE imei='$imei'";

require_once('dbConnect.php');

$lol = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($lol);

echo $myrow['imei'];

mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Что здесь не так??

Comment: интересно, `query` через `mysqli`, а `fetch_array` через `mysql`......

Comment: Не помогло, всеравно таже ошибка

Comment: значит открываем https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole и читаем, вникаем

Comment: А нет, ошибка исчезла, но нечего не отображается вообще

Comment: значит смотрим в [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php) что там говорит

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole - помогла спасибо)))))

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_POST['imei'])){

    $_DB_ = 'база';
    $_DB_USER_ = 'юзер';
    $_DB_PASSWORD_ = 'пасс';

    try {
        $_DB = new PDO(
            'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $_DB_ , $_DB_USER_ , $_DB_PASSWORD_ ,
            array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
        );
        $_DB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $_DB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $catch = "Connection reset ({$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}):<pre>".print_r($e,true).'</pre>';
        exit($catch);
    }

    $imei = make_safe( $_POST['imei'] );

    try{
        $stmt = $_DB->prepare( 'SELECT `username` FROM `user` WHERE `imei`=:imei;' );
        $stmt->execute( array( ':imei' => $imei ) );
        $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
        echo 'Connection reset:<pre>'.$e->getMessage().'</pre>';exit;
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $row );
    echo '</pre>';

}


function make_safe( $value )
{
    if( !empty( $value ) && is_string( $value ) ) { 
        $search = array( "\\",  "\x00", "\n",  "\r",  "'",  '"', "\x1a" );
        $replace = array( "\\\\","\\0","\\n", "\\r", "\'", '\"', "\\Z" );

        return str_replace( $search, $replace, strip_tags( $value ) );
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
}
```