# В чем ошибка Call to a member function fetch_assoc()?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Никак не могу найти в чем ошибка..
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\select.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\select.php(13): printResult(false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\select.php on line 3**

```
<?php
    function printResult ($result_set){
        while (($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc())!= false){
               print_r ($row);
            echo "<br/><hr/>";
        }
        echo "<br/>Количество записей равно ".$result_set->num_rows."<br/>";
    }

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mybase");
    $mysqli->query( "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT (`id`)  FROM `users`"); 
    printResult($result_set);
    $mysqli->close();

    ?>
```

Comment: Попробуйте `while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()){`

Comment: все равно не работает(

Comment: Значит, возможно `$result_set` имеет тип `bool`

Comment: да, так есть. подскажите как его преобразовать и на каком этапе.

Comment: Покажите мне где хоть раз вы проверили на ошибки? В этом и ошибка, что вы даже не удосужились проверить на ошибки. И не нужно писать`SET NAMES utf8` для этого существует метод `set_charset`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Answer (score 1):

```
$result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT (`id`)  FROM `users`");
```

> mysqli::query() возвращает FALSE в случае неудачи. В случае успешного выполнения
> запросов SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE или EXPLAIN mysqli_query() вернет
> объект mysqli_result. Для остальных успешных запросов mysqli_query()
> вернет TRUE.

[mysqli::query()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php)

Замените

```
printResult($result_set);
```

на

```
if ($result_set !== false) {
    printResult($result_set);
} else { // обработка ошибки
    trigger_error($mysqli->error);
}
```

Чтобы получить сообение об ошибке от `mysqli`

Comment: FUNCTION mybase.COUNT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: вот такая ошибка, что функция попросту не существует

Comment: @VladyslavAlifanov попробуйте `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users`

Comment: @VladyslavAlifanov нагуглил, что дело может быть в пробеле после названия функции

Comment: Вообще не помогло.