# Неполучения исправить ошибку

Tags: php, mysql, sql, запрос, mysqli

Выводит ошибку:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

как это можно исправить

```
$pol = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT sum,time,comenter FROM out");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($pol)){//"ошибка в этой строке" 
echo "
  <tr>
    <td>".$row['sum']."</td>
    <td>".$row['time']."</td>
    <td>".$row['comenter']."</td>
  </tr>";
};
```

Answer (score 3):

mysqli_query возвращает FALSE в случае неудачи.
в таком случае функция mysqli_fetch_row будет вызвана с параметром false

[Вот документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: как можно это исправить??

Comment: Оберните код цикла в проверку if($pol)

Comment: @max http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole читайте, там всё написано и пользуйтесь поиском пожалуйста

Answer (score -1):

А так?:

```
$pol = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT sum,time,comenter FROM `out`");
```