# Как можно исправить данную ошибку? php

Tags: php, sql, запрос, mysqli

> Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

не знаю как можно исправить. Помогите пожалуйста

`$pol = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT sum,time,comenter FROM out WHERE udi=");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($pol)){
if(isset($row)){
echo "<tr><td>".$row['sum']."</td><td>".$row['time']."</td><td>".$row['comenter']."</td></tr>";
}};`

Comment: Неверный SQL-запрос, в конце нет значения, с которым сравнивается `udi`. В результате вместо набора записей возвращается `false` как индикация об ошибке.

Comment: Вы читали вот этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole , который вам дали в вашем https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603133/warning-mysql-fetch-assoc-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82  вопросе ? или мнугабукаф ниасилил? ....... и зачем вы их плодите?? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604116

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется что у вас не до конца оформлен запрос:

```
$pol = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT sum,time,comenter FROM out WHERE udi=");

WHERE udi=
```

Так как запрос неверный, переменная $pol, получает неявным преобразованием булевый тип, который не может быть обработан "mysql_fetch_row"