# Не работает запрос MySQL в PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Использую [`phpMyAdmin`](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/), сам запрос там работает. Нужно вывести в таблицу собаку, владельца и тип сертификата.

```
<?
include 'db_connect.php';
    $n = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM applications WHERE type ='titul'");
    for ($i=0; $i<mysql_num_rows($n); $i++) {
      echo "<tr>";
      $num = mysql_fetch_array($n);
      $dogs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE user_id='$num[user_id]'");
      $d = mysql_fetch_array($dogs);
      $owner = mysql_query("SELECT 'certificate_application.dog_id', 'certificate_application.user_id', 'certificate_application.app_id', 'certificate_application.certificate', 'users.user_name', 'dogs.dog_name'
      FROM 'certificate_application, users', 'dogs'
      WHERE 'certificate_application.user_id' = 'users.user_id'
      AND 'certificate_application.dog_id' = 'dogs.dog_id'");
      $d = mysql_fetch_array($owner);
      echo "<td>".($i+1)."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$num[date]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$d[dog_name]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$d[user_surname] ."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$d[certificate]."</td>";
//        echo "<td>".$num[status]."</td>";
?>
```

Comment: Очень желательно описать как выглядит это "не работает" словами русского языка.

Comment: `$dogs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE user_id='{$num[user_id]}'");`

Comment: При вводе запроса "SELECT 'certificate_application.dog_id', 'certificate_application.user_id', 'certificate_application.app_id', 'certificate_application.certificate', 'users.user_name', 'dogs.dog_name'
      FROM 'certificate_application, users', 'dogs'
      WHERE 'certificate_application.user_id' = 'users.user_id'
      AND 'certificate_application.dog_id' = 'dogs.dog_id'"
в базу данных выводится нужный результат, но на сайт не выводит ничего и пишет, что ошибка именно в этом запросе (пишет, что Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT certificate_application.dog_id, certificate_application.user_id,
certificate_application.app_id, certificate_application.certificate, 
users.user_name, dogs.dog_name FROM certificate_application, users, dogs 
WHERE certificate_application.user_id = users.user_id AND 
certificate_application.dog_id = dogs.dog_id;"
```

Чувствуете разницу? Зачем вы ставите кавычки там, где они не нужны? Для экранирования имён столбцов и таблиц используется символ "`" а не одинарная кавычка.

П.С. Только люди, которые изучают php по книжкам 90-х используют `mysql_*` функции. Всё прогрессивное человечество использует `PDO`