# Call to a member function rowCount() on boolean

Tags: php

```
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hope', 'root', '', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}

$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `site`");
if ($sql->rowCount() != 0) {
    $site = $sql->fetch();
}
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowCount()
>   on boolean in /var/www/html/index.php:30\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n 
>   thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 30

Ругается на строчку `if ($sql->rowCount() != 0) {`

в чем проблема?

Comment: `$db->query("SELECT * FROM ``site``")` вернуло ошибку, может таблицы нет или что то еще пошло не так

Comment: "PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure." У вас `$sql` boolean, так что ошибка при выполнении запроса.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Comment: Проблему решил, оказывается действительно не было такой таблицы (залил не тот дамп)