# Класс Connection. Класс Query. PHP

Tags: php, mysql, классы, mysqli, инспекция-кода

Есть два класса 
***Первый***

```
<?php
  class Connection
  {
    protected $connection;
    private $host;
    private $connect_user;
    private $connect_pass;
    private $db_name;

    public function __construct($host, $connect_user, $connect_pass, $db_name)
    {
      $this->host = $host;
      $this->connect_user = $connect_user;
      $this->connect_pass = $connect_pass;
      $this->db_name = $db_name;
      try
      {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->connect_user, $this->connect_pass, $this->db_name);
        echo "Nice! We connect to db. <br>";
      } 
      catch (Exception $e)
      { 
        echo "We can't connect to database. <br>" . getMessage($e) . "<br>";
      }

    }

    public function close_connect()
    {
      try
      {
        mysqli_close($this->connection);
      }
      catch(Exception $e)
      {
        echo "We can't close connection <br>" . getMessage($e) . "<br>";
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

***Второй***

```
<?php
  include_once "Connection.php";

  class Query
  {
    private $query_string;
    public $query_result;

    function __construct(Connection $obj, $query_string)
    {
      $this->query_string = $query_string;
      try
      {
        $this->query_result = mysqli_query($obj, $this->query_string);
        echo "Wonderfull! We run the query. <br>";
      }
      catch (Exception $e)
      {
        echo "We can't run the query. <br>" . getMessage($e) . "<br>";
      }

    }
  }
?>
```

Есть `index.php`
Вот:

```
<?php

  include_once "Connection.php";
  include_once "Query.php";

  $host = 'localhost';
  $connect_user = 'user';
  $connect_pass = '';
  $db_name = 'coursework';

  $db_connection = new Connection($host, $connect_user, $connect_pass, $db_name);
  $db_connection->close_connect();

  $query_string = 'SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE';
  $db_query = new Query($db_connection, $query_string);

?>
```

Когда срабатывает код то выдает Warning. Вот такой:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in /var/www/cro.ua/public_html/Query.php on line 15

Из ошибки понятно, что команда `mysqli_query()` не распознает `Connection $obj` как `mysqli_connect`, как изменить код чтобы он распознал $obj. Да и что бы вы посоветовали изменить в коде?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Comment: По моему вопрос не является дубликатом так как тут вопрос не связан с Warning, а связан с правильным построением класс Query.

Comment: Ну тут либо `код то выдает Warning. Вот такой:........От чего это?` и ты пытаешься решить *данную* проблему, тогда это дубликат............. либо  `что  вы посоветовали бы изменить в коде?`  -  и тогда вопрос о `Warning` надо убрать из вопроса и добавить метку [tag:инспекция-кода]  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ладно сейчас изменю вопрос)

Comment: Пора выкинуть весь этот  ужас и перейти на PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Вы передали не объект mysqli, а свой объект класа Connection. Попробуйте передавать $db_query = new Query($db_connection -> $connection, $query_string);, и еще нужно поменять доступ к свойству protected $connection класа Connection на public. И не нужно закрывать сразу соединения ($db_connection -> close_connect();), закрывайте после работы с базой.