# Проверка на обновление записи

Tags: php, mysql

Мне нужно проверить обновилась ли запись в mysql. Есть какая-то функция или что то еще.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.affected-rows.php / http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.exec.php

Comment: не работает `Warning: mysql_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in`

Comment: значит точно не обновилась, потому что вернула ошибку. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole