# Помогите разобраться с запросом

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Есть запрос, но в нем нету 1 поля с таблицы images
`"SELECT id, name, url, description, visible, price, amount FROM products WHERE id = $id";`
Есть запрос с join где как раз объединил 2 таблицы, но нету в нем WHERE id = $id и я не могу по id получать значение. Как мне это сделать ? куда в joine WHERE  вставляется ?
`$q = "SELECT p.id, p.name, p.url, p.description, p.visible, p.price, p.amount, i.filename  FROM products p LEFT JOIN images i ON p.id = i.product_id";`

Comment: так добавьте where ко второму запросу в самый конец

Comment: делал так и у меня ошибка Warning: reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given. В массиве объекти и я использовал rest

Comment: А это не sql ошибка, а php и не факт что она относится к sql. А если относится, то правильно обрабатывайте ошибки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole. А в where у id то же не забудьте указать из какой он таблицы, т.е. p.id=X

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.url, p.description, p.visible, p.price, p.amount, i.filename  
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN images i ON p.id = i.product_id 
WHERE p.id = $id 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: `LIMIT` без `ORDER BY` - это в лучшем случае лотерея. А в худшем - неверный результат.