# Ошибка в PHP - коде

Tags: php, mysql

Код:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","54825482","MyO");


$result = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = '$login'" ,$db) or die('Cann`t query '.mysql_error);
```

Ошибка:

mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\www...
Cann`t query mysql_error

Я понять не могу в чем проблема

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Comment: Документацию читайте http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php **Процедурный стиль**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","54825482","MyO");


$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = '$login'");
```

Comment: Этот ответ, как и все остальные, на данный момент, содержит предполагаемую (с высокой вероятностью) уязвимость типа **SQL injection**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","54825482","MyO");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = '$login'");
```

Comment: В `" "` можно и просто писать переменную. `echo "Hello $world";`

Comment: Отличается не только это

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","54825482","MyO");

$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = '$login'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if (!$result)  die('Can`t query '. mysql_error);
```

> Процедурный стиль
>
> `mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )`

[mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php)