# Ошибка MySql в php

Tags: php, mysql

Есть следующая ошибка:

> `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in line 17/`

в 17 строке следующий код:

```
else if (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail='$mail'")))
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста больше кода

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Comment: Ваш запрос не находит не одной строки в дб вот и ругается.

Comment: @Ep1demic на данный вопрос не нужно еще кода. этот вопрос задают почта каждый день и на него тут есть ответ каноничный. К сожалению все думают что их проблема уникальна и вместо того, чтобы попробовать поискать - задают вопрос :-/

Answer (score 1):

По всей видимости у Вас `mysqli_query` возвращает `FALSE`, поэтому условие `mysqli_num_rows(FALSE)` не может быть выполнено. Проверьте, есть ли элементы базы данных по запросу, который Вы составили.