# Пытаюсь вывести статьи из БД, но ничего не получается

Tags: php, mysql

## В чём именно ошибка?

2ой день пытаюсь разобраться, но всё тщетно...
Начинающий, если не трудно, выскажите критику, говнокод или нет и почему.

Заранее спасибо

**Error:** Invalid characterset or character set not supported

**Warning:** mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in W:\domains\blog_2.0\models\blog.php on line 5

**Warning:** mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in W:\domains\blog_2.0\models\blog.php on line 5

#### 5ая строка - $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

```
function articles_all($link) {
// Формируем запрос
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC");
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    
// Извлекаем данные
    $article = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $articles = array();
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < $article; $i++) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $articles[] = $row;
    }
    
    return $articles;
}   
function article_get($link, $id_artilce) {
    $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id=%d", (int)$id_article);
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    
    if (!$result)
        die(mysqli_error($link));
    
    $article = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $article;
}
function articles_intro($text, $len = 500) {
    return mb_substr($text, 0, $len);
}
```

Comment: А вы не все привели, ошибка то возникает видимо при попытке подключения к БД или установке кодировки соединения. Все остальное уже из за нее, так как подключения нет. А в приведенном фрагменте когда как раз нету подключения к БД ...

Comment: Во первых utf8 без тире. А вот почему у вас в первые две функции приходит пустой $link сами разбирайтесь, по приведенному фрагменту нельзя сказать откуда он передается и где хранится. И дополнения к вопросу надо писать не в комментариях, а по ссылке "править" под текстом вопроса. А то в комментах форматирования то нет, читать сложно

Comment: спасибо, нашёл ошибку, это первый вопрос, который кому либо задал, очень помогли

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)