# Изучаю php OOP не могу к базе подсоединится

Tags: php, mysqli

BDconfig.php

```
<?php

define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','test_user');
define('PASS','test_user');
define('DB','my_oop');


?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
include 'BDconfig.php';
include 'class/Page.php';
include 'class/Database.php';


$page = new Page();
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

}
else {
    $text = $page->get_all();
}


?>
```

В папке class Database.php

```
<?php

class Database {

    public $db;

    public function __construct($host,$user,$pass,$db) {

        $this->db = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);
        if(!$this->db) {
            exit('NO CONNECT MySQL');
        }


        if(!mysqli_select_db($db,$this->db)) {
            exit("NO TABLE");
        }

        mysqli_query("SET NAMES utf-8");

        return $this->db;

    }

    public function get_all_db() {


    }

    public function get_one_db() {

    }

}



?>
```

В папке class Page.php

```
<?php

class Page {

    public $text;

    public function get_all() {
        $db = new Database(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
        $result = $db->get_all_db();

        return $result;

    }

    public function get_one($id) {

    }

    public function get_bod() {

    }

}



?>
```

Получаю ошибку

```
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in F:\xampp\htdocs\OOP1\class\Database.php on line 15
NO TABLE
```

Что не так сделал?

Comment: Переводчиком для ошибки не пробовали пользоваться?

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр , пробовал, но ничего не понял. Что то там он ожидает.

Comment: Вам надо `mysqli_select_db($this->db, $db)` . Ну логично же - встроенная функция ругается, что что-то не то передали: забить в гугл функцию, и посмотреть - а что ей надо передавать вообще, и в каком порядке.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр теперь понял, и дальше mysqli_query($this->db,"SET NAMES utf-8");  Учусь еще.

Comment: вообще это чуть ли не главный навык программиста - то за что программистам реально платят: уметь максимально быстро отлаживать, понимать в чём проблема, и соответсвенно знать как устранить. И это не так сложно, если выработать себе  универсальный алгоритм любой отладки - если пользоваться поисковиком, SO, и вытащить максимальную информацию об ошибке (в данном случае просто прочитать). Так что советую учиться этому в первую очередь)

Comment: mysqli_select_db($this->db, $db) не поможет, конструктор ждёт 4й аргумент.

Comment: Что вы не так сделали? создали объект соединения с БД и не записали его ни во что глобальное (статическая переменная класса, статическая переменная функции, да хотя бы тупо глобальная переменная), чтобы можно было переиспользовать в течение соединения. Сразу отучайтесь так использовать объекты. Веб - это не оконные приложения. И даже не консольные. Здесь другой принцип.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Comment: @Tokwiro, и удалите во всех своих php файлах завершающие их `?>`.

Answer (score 1):

Потеряли  `$db` тут:

```
class Database {

public $db;

public function __construct($host,$user,$pass,$db) {

    $this->db = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass, /*тут*/);
```