# Ошибка Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть код

```
<?php

include "db.php";

$db = mysqli_connect($localhost, $namedb, $password, $nametable);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'test'";

$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo $array[id] . " ". $array[name]. " " . $array[username] . " " . $array[password];
}

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Выводит следующую ошибку:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /storage/ssd5/030/2080030/public_html/index.php on line 14

Что в этом коде не так?

Comment: Вам сюда [справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), И удалите ответ.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Comment: Не знаю, то ли дублем надо закрывать, то ли не надо ибо в дубле нет описание банальной ошибки

Answer (score 5):

Подробно об ошибке и что с ней делать написано тут: **[mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/423439/191482)**.

Но т.к. можно сразу не заметить ошибку, которая в том вопросе не описана и долго можно не найти - напишу в чем тут проблема:

Имена таблиц, колонок надо писать **не в одинарных кавычках** `'`. Писать их надо **в обратных** (которые находятся где буква ё на клавиатуре).

в итоге должно быть не так

```
SELECT * FROM 'test'
```

а вот так

```
SELECT * FROM `test`
```