# Как правильно составить запрос для вывода тех, кто прошёл курс полностью?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы
lesson:

```
   id  |       id_course  |  lesson_title
    1  |          3       |      Урок 1
    2  |          3       |      Урок 2
    3  |          3       |      Урок 3
    4  |          4       |      Урок 4
    5  |          4       |      Урок 5
```

history:

```
  id  |       id_lesson  |             email      |    date
  43  |          1       |     123@gmail.com      |    2018-07-09 13:17:05
  44  |          2       |     123@gmail.com      |    2018-07-09 13:18:05
  45  |          3       |     123@gmail.com      |    2018-07-09 13:19:05
```

Суть в чём, есть курсы, в них есть уроки.

Разные пользователи проходят урок -> записывается история о том что он прошёл урок.

Нужно сделать вывод людей, тех, кто полностью прошёл весь курс (т.е. все уроки в курсе).

В каждом курсе свой вывод прошедших людей.

Вот мой запрос, но не то:

```sql
SELECT
  h.*
FROM
  history h
  LEFT JOIN lesson l ON h.id_lesson = l.id
WHERE
  l.id_course= '$id'
```

Мне нужно чтобы выводило просто запись с `email` и датой, кто и когда закончил весь курс.

По логике, как я думаю, нужно сверить кол-во записей в `history` с `id` уроков каждого пользователя и кол-во самих уроков в таблице lesson по их `id` конкретного курса ->

И потом, если эти кол-ва записей совпадают, то выводить их `email`.

Как правильно составить запрос?

```
function total_score($id){
    global $connection;
   $query = "SELECT l.id_course, h.email, MAX(h.date) FROM lesson l LEFT JOIN history h ON h.id_lesson = l.id WHERE l.id_course= '$id' GROUP BY l.id_course, h.email HAVING SUM(h.id_lesson IS NULL) = 0";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $total_score = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $total_score[$row['email']] = $row;
    }
    return $total_score;
}
```

Исправил, но теперь выводит пользователя, если он хотя бы один урок прошёл, а не все три, как в этом примере.

Comment: Дату какую выводить? Последнего урока пользователя? И что такое "пользователь"? Как отличить одного пользователя от другого?

Comment: да, последнего урока. Пользователь отличается по email

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Набор запросов с последовательным приближением к результату**

> ```
> create table `lesson`
> (
>   `id` int,
>   `id_course` int,
>   `lesson_title` text
> );
> ```

> ```
> create table history 
> (
>   `id` int,
>   `id_lesson` int,
>   `email` text,
>   `date` date
> );
> ```

> ```
> Insert into `lesson` (`id`,`id_course`,`lesson_title`) values 
> (1, 3, 'Урок 1'),
> (2, 3, 'Урок 2'),
> (3, 3, 'Урок 3'),
> (4, 4, 'Урок 4'),
> (5, 4, 'Урок 5')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> Insert into `history` (`id`,`id_lesson`,`email`,`date`) values 
> (43, 1, '100@gmail.com', '2018-07-10'),
> (44, 2, '100@gmail.com', '2018-07-11'),
> (45, 3, '100@gmail.com', '2018-07-12'),
> (46, 4, '110@gmail.com', '2018-07-13'),
> (47, 5, '110@gmail.com', '2018-07-14'),
> (48, 1, '200@gmail.com', '2018-07-15'),
> (49, 2, '200@gmail.com', '2018-07-16'),
> (50, 1, '300@gmail.com', '2018-07-17'),
> (51, 4, '300@gmail.com', '2018-07-18')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select * from `lesson`;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | id_course | lesson_title
> -: | --------: | :-----------
>  1 |         3 | Урок 1  
>  2 |         3 | Урок 2  
>  3 |         3 | Урок 3  
>  4 |         4 | Урок 4  
>  5 |         4 | Урок 5
> ```

> ```
> select * from `history`;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | id_lesson | email         | date      
> -: | --------: | :------------ | :---------
> 43 |         1 | 100@gmail.com | 2018-07-10
> 44 |         2 | 100@gmail.com | 2018-07-11
> 45 |         3 | 100@gmail.com | 2018-07-12
> 46 |         4 | 110@gmail.com | 2018-07-13
> 47 |         5 | 110@gmail.com | 2018-07-14
> 48 |         1 | 200@gmail.com | 2018-07-15
> 49 |         2 | 200@gmail.com | 2018-07-16
> 50 |         1 | 300@gmail.com | 2018-07-17
> 51 |         4 | 300@gmail.com | 2018-07-18
> ```

**Получить курсы которые проходил ученик**

> ```
> select distinct 
>   h.`email`,
>   l.`id_course`
> from `lesson` l
>  join `history` h on l.`id` = h.`id_lesson`
> ```
>
> ```
> email         | id_course
> :------------ | --------:
> 100@gmail.com |         3
> 110@gmail.com |         4
> 200@gmail.com |         3
> 300@gmail.com |         3
> 300@gmail.com |         4
> ```

**Получить полный список занятий, которые  должен пройти ученик для завершения курсов** (но не все занятия ученик прошел, например 200@gmail.com не прошел в курсе 3 занятие 3)

> ```
> select 
>   cr.`email`,
>   cr.`id_course`,
>   L0.`id` as id_lesson
> from
>   (
>     select distinct 
>       h.`email`,
>       L.`id_course`
>     from `lesson` L
>       join `history` h on L.`id` = h.`id_lesson`
>   ) as cr
>   join `lesson` L0 on cr.`id_course` = L0.`id_course`
> order by 
>   cr.`email` asc,
>   cr.`id_course` asc,
>   L0.`id` asc
> ```
>
> ```
> email         | id_course | id_lesson
> :------------ | --------: | --------:
> 100@gmail.com |         3 |         1
> 100@gmail.com |         3 |         2
> 100@gmail.com |         3 |         3
> 110@gmail.com |         4 |         4
> 110@gmail.com |         4 |         5
> 200@gmail.com |         3 |         1
> 200@gmail.com |         3 |         2
> 200@gmail.com |         3 |         3
> 300@gmail.com |         3 |         1
> 300@gmail.com |         3 |         2
> 300@gmail.com |         3 |         3
> 300@gmail.com |         4 |         4
> 300@gmail.com |         4 |         5
> ```

**Реальная таблица прохождения/непрохождения занятий (уроков)**

> ```
> -- полная таблица прохождения/непрохождения уроков
> select 
>   L1.`email`,
>   L1.`id_course`,
>   L1.`id_lesson`,
>   H1.`email`
> from
>   (
>   select 
>     cr.`email`,
>     cr.`id_course`,
>     L0.`id` as id_lesson
>   from
>     (
>       select distinct 
>         h.`email`,
>         L.`id_course`
>       from `lesson` L
>         join `history` h on L.`id` = h.`id_lesson`
>     ) as cr
>     join `lesson` L0 on cr.`id_course` = L0.`id_course`
>   ) L1 
>   left outer join `history` H1
>   on 
>     H1.`email` = L1.`email`
>     and H1.`id_lesson` = L1.`id_lesson`
> order BY 
>   L1.`email`,
>   L1.`id_course`,
>   L1.`id_lesson`
> ```
>
> ```
> email         | id_course | id_lesson | email        
> :------------ | --------: | --------: | :------------
> 100@gmail.com |         3 |         1 | 100@gmail.com
> 100@gmail.com |         3 |         2 | 100@gmail.com
> 100@gmail.com |         3 |         3 | 100@gmail.com
> 110@gmail.com |         4 |         4 | 110@gmail.com
> 110@gmail.com |         4 |         5 | 110@gmail.com
> 200@gmail.com |         3 |         1 | 200@gmail.com
> 200@gmail.com |         3 |         2 | 200@gmail.com
> 200@gmail.com |         3 |         3 | null         
> 300@gmail.com |         3 |         1 | 300@gmail.com
> 300@gmail.com |         3 |         2 | null         
> 300@gmail.com |         3 |         3 | null         
> 300@gmail.com |         4 |         4 | 300@gmail.com
> 300@gmail.com |         4 |         5 | null
> ```

**Выбираем кто не прошел курс**

> ```
> -- ученик не прошел весь курс
> select distinct
>   L1.`email`,
>   L1.`id_course`
> from
>   (
>   select 
>     cr.`email`,
>     cr.`id_course`,
>     L0.`id` as id_lesson
>   from
>     (
>       select distinct 
>         h.`email`,
>         L.`id_course`
>       from `lesson` L
>         join `history` h on L.`id` = h.`id_lesson`
>     ) as cr
>     join `lesson` L0 on cr.`id_course` = L0.`id_course`
>   ) L1 
>   left outer join `history` H1
>   on 
>     H1.`email` = L1.`email`
>     and H1.`id_lesson` = L1.`id_lesson`
> where 
>   H1.`email` is null
> ```
>
> ```
> email         | id_course
> :------------ | --------:
> 300@gmail.com |         3
> 200@gmail.com |         3
> 300@gmail.com |         4
> ```

**Получаем даты последних занятий курсов, которые прошел ученик**

> ```
>     select 
>       h.`email`,
>       L.`id_course`,
>       max(h.`date`) as `max_date`
>     from `lesson` L
>       join `history` h on L.`id` = h.`id_lesson`
>     group by 
>       h.`email`,
>       L.`id_course`
> ```
>
> ```
> email         | id_course | max_date  
> :------------ | --------: | :---------
> 100@gmail.com |         3 | 2018-07-12
> 110@gmail.com |         4 | 2018-07-14
> 200@gmail.com |         3 | 2018-07-16
> 300@gmail.com |         3 | 2018-07-17
> 300@gmail.com |         4 | 2018-07-18
> ```

**РЕЗУЛЬТАТ: пользователи прошедшие курс**

> ```
> -- РЕЗУЛЬТАТ: пользователи прошедшие курс
>
> select
>   L3.`email`,
>   L3.`id_course`,
>   T07.`max_date`
> from
>   (
>   select distinct 
>     h.`email`,
>     l.`id_course`
>   from `lesson` l
>     join `history` h on l.`id` = h.`id_lesson`
>   ) L3 left outer join  
>   (
>   select distinct
>     L1.`email`,
>     L1.`id_course`
>   from
>     (
>     select 
>       cr.`email`,
>       cr.`id_course`,
>       L0.`id` as id_lesson
>     from
>       (
>         select distinct 
>           h.`email`,
>           L.`id_course`
>         from `lesson` L
>           join `history` h on L.`id` = h.`id_lesson`
>       ) as cr
>       join `lesson` L0 on cr.`id_course` = L0.`id_course`
>     ) L1 
>     left outer join `history` H1
>     on 
>       H1.`email` = L1.`email`
>       and H1.`id_lesson` = L1.`id_lesson`
>   where 
>     H1.`email` is null
>   ) L2 on 
>       L2.`email` = L3.`email`
>       and L2.`id_course` = L3.`id_course`
>   join
>   (
>     select 
>       h.`email`,
>       L.`id_course`,
>       max(h.`date`) as `max_date`
>     from `lesson` L
>       join `history` h on L.`id` = h.`id_lesson`
>     group by 
>       h.`email`,
>       L.`id_course`
>   ) as T07
>   on
>       T07.`email` = L3.`email`
>       and T07.`id_course` = L3.`id_course`
> where
>  L2.`email` is null
>  and L3.`id_course` = 4 -- Ограничиваем одним курсом 
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> email         | id_course | max_date  
> :------------ | --------: | :---------
> 110@gmail.com |         4 | 2018-07-14
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=aaa3232996e12f32eaf5d841cf19c8de)*

Comment: Ничего себе! Спасибо вам большое. Только есть пару вопросов: 

1. В последнем запросе нужно вывести ещё "date" последнего прошедшего урока, соответственно это и будет время прохождения всего курса.

2. Не понимаю как определяется id курса, т.к. в своей функции я его передавал как $id и использовал, а тут как?

3. И не могли бы вы написать пару источников с информацией о таких запросах, чтобы можно было их понять и разобрать самостоятельно, а то это слишком круто для меня пока что.

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Использовался стандарт ansi sql, соединения join, только их больше двух, поэтому кажется все запутанным. 
    Каждый шаг в https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=aaa3232996e12f32eaf5d841cf19c8de использует предыдущий запрос и приближает запрос к цели.
    Можно смотреть на результаты запросов, и проверять как происходит соединение (join) по данным.

Comment: Спасибо вам, что потратили на меня время. Всё работает как надо. Буду разбираться что к чему.

Answer (score 2):

Для всех курсов - где-то так:

```
SELECT l.id_course, h.email, MAX(h.date)
FROM lesson l
LEFT JOIN history h ON h.id_lesson = l.id
GROUP BY l.id_course, h.email
HAVING SUM(h.id_lesson IS NULL) = 0
```

Для одного заданного курса - добавить WHERE.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас потестю

Comment: Исправил, но теперь выводит пользователя, если он хотя бы один урок прошёл, а не все три, как в этом примере.