# Вывод запроса sql в html

Tags: php, sql

Есть задача: пользователь вводит в вебстраницу номер учебной группы, идёт запрос sql, пользователю возвращается расписание на сегодня.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Расписание</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require 'connect.php'; // Подключает файл с логином/паролем и именем БД
mysqli_set_charset($a,'utf8'); // Устанавливает кодировку клиента
$sql_select  = 'SELECT * FROM `pisos`'; // Выбираем таблицу из которой читать данные
$result = mysqli_query($a, $sql_select); // Запрос к БД
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); // Разбираем полученый массив 
do
{
  printf("<p>Номер группы: ".$row['group_number']."</p><p>Дисциплина: ".$row['task_name']."</p><p>Преподаватель: ".$row['task_family']."</p>----------------------------------------<b>");
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
?>
<form method="post" action="index.html">
<input id="submitback" type="submit" value="На главную">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP выводит две ошибки:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/admin/data/www/site/allauthor.php on line 15
<p>Номер группы: </p><p>Дисциплина: </p><p>Преподаватель: </p>----------------------------------------<b>PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/admin/data/www/site/allauthor.php on line 20
```

В чём причина и как это исправить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Comment: добавьте в коннект и в запрос обработку ошибок - и все станет ясно

Answer (score 0):

Что-то не то с `$result`, попробуйте вывести через просто `$result` и гляньте, скорее всего проблема в том, что в переменную ничего не записывается.

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже сталкивался такими проблемами) Раз вы передали перемену $a (Думаю это подключение к базе данных) на mysqli_query, передайти и на mysqli_fetch_array.

```
<?php
require 'connect.php'; // Подключает файл с логином/паролем и именем БД
mysqli_set_charset($a,'utf8'); // Устанавливает кодировку клиента
$sql_select  = 'SELECT * FROM `pisos`'; // Выбираем таблицу из которой читать данные
$result = mysqli_query($a, $sql_select); // Запрос к БД
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($a, $result); // Разбираем полученый массив 
do
{
  printf("<p>Номер группы: ".$row['group_number']."</p><p>Дисциплина: ".$row['task_name']."</p><p>Преподаватель: ".$row['task_family']."</p>----------------------------------------<b>");
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
?>
```

Если это не работает, то попробуйте поменять местами mysqli_query($sql_select , $a ) и тд

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_query()` возвращает `mysqli_result|bool`

> Возвращает false в случае возникновения ошибки. В случае успешного
> выполнения запросов, которые создают набор результатов, таких как
> SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE или EXPLAIN, mysqli_query() вернёт объект
> mysqli_result. Для остальных успешных запросов mysqli_query() вернёт
> true.

в твоем случае это false, о чем и говорится в ошибке "...boolean given in..."

собственно, где создание коннекта к базе?

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','user','pass','database');
```

или это в `connect.php`? Тогда не мешало бы там же сделать проверку на ошибки.

[курим тут](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php)