# Как удалить из базы данных авторизованного пользователя?

Tags: php, mysql

На странице имеется кнопка "Удалить аккаунт", которая ведет на страницу delete_account.php. Нужно чтобы при нажатии на нее авторизованный пользователь удалял свою строку из таблицы. Целый день мучаюсь с этой проблемой. Не подскажите как решить?
Часть кода страницы delete_account.php

```
    $host = 'localhost';  
    $user = 'root';    
    $pass = 'root'; 
    $db_name = 'diploma';

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
    mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    if (isset($_GET['user'])) {
        $user = $_GET ['user'];
        $query = "DELETE FROM `username` WHERE `name` = 'user'";
        mysqli_query($link, $query);
    }
```

Не кидайтесь палками, я всего лишь прошу дать совет, я не такой опытный)
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `username` - это такое имя таблицы? какое-то оно необычное... А где Вы проверяете, что Ваши обращения к серверу (mysqli_connect, mysqli_query) не закончились неудачей?

Comment: username - это имя таблицы. Я вроде проверял и мне выводились данные из базы. Сейчас попробую  повторно.

Comment: Попробовал проверить через ```if($link) {
  echo 'Соединение установлено.';
 } else {
  die('Ошибка подключения к серверу баз данных.');
 } ``` - Пишет соединение установлено.

Comment: Аналогично нужно поступить с обоими mysqli_query. Ну и если не false - посмотреть, что же собсно там приехало.

Comment: Переменная $query при проверке выдала ошибку.

Comment: Угу... ожидаемо. У Вас в таблице точно есть пользователь с именем "user"? а то там что-то долларов маловато...

Comment: Нет, user, как я понимаю, это имя пользователя в сессии. Но я могу ошибаться. Вот скриншот таблицы - https://prnt.sc/ssj9ny

Comment: *как я понимаю, это имя пользователя в сессии* Да щазз! вот будь там `'$user'` - то да. А так - нет... это просто строковый литерал со значением `'user'`. А такого значения в поле `\`user\`` нету...

Comment: Я уже пробовал и с $, и без, и с одинарными кавычками, и с двойными, и без них - ничего не помогло. Сейчас попробовал как вы сказали, выдает ошибку при проверке переменной $query.

Comment: Покажите содержимое этой переменной после подстановки имени пользователя.

Comment: @Akina "Аналогично нужно поступить с обоими mysqli_query" - [не нужно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423446/179379)

Comment: @Akina При выполнении функции ```print ($_COOKIE['user'])``` выдает значение из поля "name" таблицы.

Comment: **а зачем ты его тогда из $_GET берёшь?**

Comment: @Ипатьев Но у него как бы нет "boolean given"...

Comment: @Ипатьев Спасибо огромное! Работает!!!

Comment: ну еще  бы оно не работало. любой студент у итоге может удалить всех остальных

Comment: @Ипатьев Почему? Если не затруднит, объясните, пожалуйста, простыми словами.

Comment: ну если уж ты не можешь одну переменную от другой отличить, то вряд ли поймешь хоть слово из того что я скажу.  В куки любой может написать что угодно, и как следствие удалить кого угодно. В твой SQL запрос любой авторизованный пользователь может написать что угодно, и как следствие удалить хоть всю таблицу целиком

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```php
$query = "DELETE FROM `username` WHERE `name` = '$user'";
```

---

Но я бы для начала удостоверился в следующих пунктах:

- Подключились ли вы к базе данных вообще?
- Действительно ли в `GET` параметре name находится имя пользователя
- Действительно ли таблица называется `username`

---

Еще вам не мешало бы обернуть входной параметр в `mysql_escape_string`

```php
$query = "DELETE FROM username WHERE name = '". mysql_escape_string($user) ."'"
```

Это необходимо для предотвращения SQL инъекций. Чтоб понять зачем это нужно, попробуйте без `mysql_escape_string` попробовать удалить юзера с именем `' or True or '`*(именно так, имя должно начинаться и заканчиваться с одинарной кавычки)* и посмотрите, что случится в базе данных

Comment: Спасибо огромное за совет, но я уже решил свою проблему. У меня name находился не в GET параметре.