# Вывод строки по id в php

Tags: php

Из сайта A на сайт B переносит id, с этим проблем нет.. Не получается по id отобразить нужную строчку(id хранится в $page).В чем может быть проблема? Буду благодарен

```
//сайт A
<?php
$str= mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mysql', 'mysql', 'animals');



$select= mysqli_query($str, "SELECT * FROM `animals`.`articles`;");
while ($r= mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
        
    
        echo '( '.$r['id'].' ) <a href=../animals/animal.php?id='.$r['id'].'>'.$r['title'].'</a><br>';
         echo $r['text'] .'<br>';
}
mysqli_close($str);
?>




//Сайт Б

<?php 
$page = $_GET['id'];
$str= mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mysql', 'mysql', 'animals');


$result = mysqli_query($str, "SELECT * FROM animals WHERE id='$page'");
while ($r1=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){echo $r1['text'];}

?>
```

Comment: Например в том, что id в БД какой-нибудь int, а вы даёте string

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701145/191482  и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482

Comment: Из ошибок вот это есть:Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)