# Как получить в php файле поле из базы данных?

Tags: php, база-данных

Я пытаюсь вывести значение одного поля, одной строки(потому что login уникальный), но в result возвращается что-то не то, не понимаю почему, возможно я что-то не так делаю?

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$user_login = $_POST["user_login"];
$mysql_qry = "select user_rank * from user where user_login like '$user_login'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_qry);
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: посмотрите примеры того, что делать с mysli result

Comment: "что-то не то" --- какое точное описание))

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну там просто были очень страшные вещи, поэтому мое пояснение примерно такое же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user_login = $_POST["user_login"];    

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select user_rank, * from user where user_login like ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user_login);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$assoc = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

процедурно:

```
$user_login = $_POST["user_login"];   

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "select user_rank, * from user where user_login like ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $user_login);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
$assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Соответствующие доки:

- https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.execute.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: А можете объяснить  что происходит здесь mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $user_login);?  Возвращает true если..? или false при ошибке.
И mysqli_fetch_assoc возвращает массив, но вроде как результатом должна быть одна ячейка из таблицы, не совсем понимаю как это работает.

Comment: Просто пытаюсь воспользоваться вашим ответом, а выводит ошибку 
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected 's' (T_STRING) in ...

Comment: А теперь <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, bool given in ...

Comment: @LoL ты ообще доки когда-нибудь открывал? https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @Jean-Claude, ну я читаю пытаюсь понять, потому что по сути работаю с этим впервые, поэтому спрашиваю вопросы которые я не совсем понимаю, я понимаю что в ответе $stmt должен быть mysqli_stmt, но я не понимаю, как тогда ответ мне может помочь и не запутать меня, а если я им неправильно пользуюсь, то хотелось бы понять что не так

Comment: @LoL  " результатом должна быть одна ячейка из таблицы,"  - у вас в запросе было написано `user_rank, * ` а это не одна ячейка.  В любом случае взятие ассоциативного массива - самое оно, потому что позволит обратиться так: `$assoc['user_rank']`.......`mysqli_stmt_bind_param` привязывает переменные к запросу. s - означает что переменная строковая (см. доки по bind param). Привязывать к запросу нужно так, потому что это защищает от SQL инъекций........."mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, bool given"  --- значит  у вас запрос возвращает false - то есть неверный запрос

Comment: @LoL "syntax error, unexpected 's'" --- вроде не должно быть.. ошибка синтаксиса

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, как я понимаю просто надо написать `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $user_login);`, а неверный запрос он может быть по какой причине, например я запрашиваю значения которых в таблице нет? или что-то еще, просто именно в самом запросе я не сомневаюсь и не могу понять причину ошибки

Comment: @LoL " как я понимаю просто надо написать mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $user_login);, "  ---- а в чём отличие?)) в одинарной кавычке? по идее разницы не должно быть. ..........."неверный запрос он может быть по какой причине, " - их десятки......... попробуйте включить отображение ошибок  и по этому поводу воспользоваться ответом отсюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423446/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну как показали сообщения об ошибках, с одинарными кавычками он перестал ругаться на синтаксис

Comment: @LoL попробуйте две вещи: 1) убедиться что логин пароль и БД в подключении указанны верно 2) исполнить запрос без подготовленных переменных, хотя бы банально `SELECT * FROM user where user_login ='test'`  (вместо test свой логин) и проверить на нём....и уже от этого идти к бОльшему

Comment: @АлексейШиманский оказывается * может все поломать 
`"SELECT user_rank FROM user WHERE user_login like ?" `

Comment: @LoL забавно. видимо mysql не может понять что звёздочка относится к определённой таблице... а вот  `SELECT user_rank, user.* FROM user......` работает нормально.... странно..  А в Postgresql работает такой запрос штатно)) Хорошо. что разобрались