# Что означает эта ошибка? (parse, syntax, warning, fatal)

Tags: php, отладка, обработка-ошибок, php-faq

Все сталкиваются с ошибками. Даже опытные программисты допускают опечатки. Возникают, например, синтаксические ошибки.
Это ряд ответов о предупреждениях, ошибках и уведомлениях, с которыми вы можете столкнуться при программировании на PHP и не знаете, как их исправить.

Особенно часто проблемы с пониманием возникают у **русскоязычного разработчика**, т.к. все сообщения на  ̶э̶л̶ь̶ф̶и̶й̶с̶к̶о̶м̶ английском, поэтому данные пояснения будут особо полезны.

---

Ссылки на другие способы нахождения ожибок:

- **[Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/)**
- **[PHP parse/syntax errors; Ошибки Unexpected XXX и как решить их](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1437802)**

---

### Найдите ошибку в списке ниже и перейдите к ответу с её описанием.

P.S. Ошибки выделены в группы не по контексту и логической принадлежности, а для того, чтобы не плодить по одному ответу на каждую ошибку.

---

- Общие предварительные проверки.

  - Ничего не видно. Страница пустая и белая.
  - Код не запускается / Выводится код как он есть в PHP

**[Перейти к блоку с ответами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1364091/191482)**

---

- Notice: Undefined variable / Notice: Undefined property
- Warning: [function] expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
- Warning: [function]: failed to open stream
- Warning: Division by zero
- Warning: Illegal string offset 'XXX' | Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string (PHP 8.0)
- Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

**[Перейти к блоку с ответами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1364095/191482)**

---

- Fatal error: Call to a member function ... on a non-object
- Fatal error: Call to undefined function XXX
- Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class *[class name]* / Fatal error: Cannot redeclare *[function name]*
- Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

**[Перейти к блоку с ответами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1364103/191482)**

---

- Fatal error: Declaration of AAA::BBB() must be compatible with that of CCC::BBB()
- Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
- Fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to a string
- Fatal error: Undefined class constant
- Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: some_function(): Argument #1 must be of type XXX, YYY given

**[Перейти к блоку с ответами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1364428/191482)**

---

- Notice: Array to string conversion
- Notice: Trying to get property of non-object error

**[Перейти к блоку с ответами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1364429/191482)**

---

- Notice: Undefined Index (Undefined array key) / Undefined offset
- Notice: Uninitialized string offset: XXX
- Notice: Use of undefined constant XXX - assumed 'XXX' / Warning: Use of undefined constant XXX - assumed 'XXX' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

**[Перейти к блоку с ответами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1364430/191482)**

---

- Strict Standards: Non-static method [<class>::<method>] should not be called statically
- Warning: function() expects parameter XXX to be boolean (or integer, string, etc), YYY given
- Deprecated: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated

**[Перейти к блоку с ответами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1364432/191482)**

Answer (score 3):

Общие предварительные проверки.

---

##### ### Ничего не видно. Страница пустая и белая.

Это происходит, когда отчеты об ошибках отключены и произошла фатальная ошибка (часто синтаксическая ошибка). Если это происходит не на продакшн версии, а при разработке, то достаточно включить отображение ошибок. Как это сделать, написано тут:
**[Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде - Сообщения об ошибках PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701145/191482)**. Если это продакшн версия, то ошибки обычно логируются в специальный файл. Как правило на Линукс системах лежит в папке `/var/log/apache2`
с названием "error.log" либо "название-сайта-error.log". Там можно найти конкретное сообщение об ошибке.

---

**Просто напоминание:** для проверки на корреткность логики кода, когда работает, но не так, как ожидалось, используйте **[отладку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482)**

##### ### Код не запускается / Выводится код как он есть в PHP

Если не видно результата от PHP-кода и/или видно части PHP кода прямо на странице как они есть, значит PHP не выполняется. Если посмотреть в исходный код страницы в своем браузере (View Source),
то поскольку код PHP пишется в тегах `<?php ?>`, браузер попытается интерпретировать их как теги *HTML* и результат может выглядеть несколько запутанным.

Надо знать, чтобы запустить PHP-скрипты, необходимо:

- веб-сервер, который выполняет скрипт
- установить расширение файла на `.php`, иначе веб-сервер не будет интерпретировать его как таковой (<sub>Если вы его не перенастроите (всё можно перенастроить)</sub>)
- обращаться к файлу `.php` **через веб-сервер**! Если просто дважды кликнуть файл, он, скорее всего, откроется в браузере с таким адресом:

  ```
  file://C:/path/to/my/file.php
  ```

  Это полностью игнорирует любой запущенный веб-сервер, и файл не интерпретируется. Нужно "посетить" URL-адрес файла именно на веб-сервере. Примерно так:

  ```
  http://localhost/my/file.php
  ```

---

**Напоминание:** Если используете короткие открытые теги `<?` вместо `<?php`, надо проверить, что в конфигурации PHP (php.ini) включена опция `short_open_tag = On`

Answer (score 3):

##### ### Notice: Undefined variable

Происходит при попытке использовать переменную, которая ранее не была определена. То есть обращаетесь, например, к переменной `$test`, пишите `if($test){ echo $actionMessage; }`,
а в коде выше её нет, либо она в другой области видимости (например за пределами анонимной функции)

```
$prefix = "Blueberry";
$food = ["cake", "cheese", "pie"];
$prefixedFood = array_map(function ($food) { // должно быть array_map(function ($food) use ($prefix) {
 // $prefix не определён, т.к. в другой области видимости                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^ надо передать в функцию
  return "${prefix} ${food}";
}, $food);
```

или определяется только в одной из веток `if`, а код попадает в другую

```
$a = 10;
if($a == 5) {
    $user_location = 'Paris';
} else {
}

echo $user_location;
```

и т.д. Смотрите наличие этой переменной выше по коду и в правильной области видимости!

##### ### Notice: Undefined property

Эта ошибка означает то же, что выше, но относится к свойству объекта. Т.е. например обращение `if($obj->test){ echo $actionMessage; }`, при отсутствии свойства `test` в объекте вызовет ошибку.

---

##### ### Warning: [function] expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Самая распространённая проблема [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/423439/191482). См. ссылку для подробного описания.

Сама ошибка говорит о том, что в какую-либо из функций подали на вход переменную с типом `boolean`, а она ждала тип "ресурс".
Ресурс - это [тип](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php), такой же как строки, целые числа и пр.
Некоторые функции в PHP возвращают данный тип, например `mysql_query`, `curl_init`, `fopen` и многие другие (смотрите в документации, что возвращает функция).
Однако если функция отработала некорректно, то в качестве результата она может вернуть `false` (всё тот же `fopen`, например, или `mysql_query`). Поэтому надо проверять что вернула функция: `boolean` (по-сути, неудачу операции) или корректный дескриптор.

```
$fp = fopen(...);

if (!$fp) {
    trigger_error('Failed to allocate resource');
    exit;
}

$data = fread($fp, 1024);
```

---

##### ### Warning: [function]: failed to open stream

Происходит, когда вызывается файл (обычно с помощью `include`, `require` или `fopen`). Частые варианты проблемы:

- Файл не существует в принципе
- Отсутствует даже сама папка
- Путь до файла неверный
- Путь до файла относительный (а указали абсолютный или неправильно рассчитан путь, не учтена вложенность и пр.)
- Путь подключаемого файла (через include, require) неверный
- Путь вроде похожий, но на самом деле там опечатки
- Неправильные права на папку или файл (например 000 вместо 755)
- Файлы в ПО компилируются и кэшируются. Путь поменялся, а кэш забыли сбросить

Одна из распространенных ошибок - не использовать абсолютный путь. Это можно легко решить, используя полный путь или магические константы, такие как `__DIR__` или `dirname (__ FILE__)`:

```
include __DIR__ . '/inc/globals.inc.php';
```

или

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc/globals.inc.php';
```

---

##### ### Warning: Division by zero

Происходит деление на ноль. Это может быть не только потому, что в переменной-делителе 0, но и если в ней `NULL`. Самое простое это **[воспользоваться отладкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482)**. и посмотреть почему в переменной не то значение, что ожидалось. Нужно переписать свое выражение так, чтобы проверить, что значение не равно 0. Также можно воспользоваться **[try/catch](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php#language.exceptions.examples)** для отлова исключения и уведомления об этом пользователя, например.

```
$var1 = 0;
$var2 = 5;

try {
    $var3 = $var2 / $var1;
} catch (DivisionByZeroError $e) {
    echo 'Произошло деление на ноль!';
}
```

---

##### ### Warning: Illegal string offset 'XXX' | Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string (PHP 8.0)

Происходит при попытке получить доступ к элементу массива с синтаксисом квадратных скобок, но делаете это в строке, а не в массиве, поэтому операция явно не имеет смысла. Пример

```
$myString = "string";

// Ту всё ок
echo $myString[0]; // s
echo $myString[1]; // t
echo $myString[2]; // r
// ...

// !! Ошибка:
echo $myString['port'];
// !! Warning: Illegal string offset 'port' in ...
```

Если известно, что в переменной должен (обязан) быть массив - можно воспользоваться **[отладкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482)**, чтобы отследить, почему в какой момент в переменной вместо массива значение меняется на строковое. Если не известно, прилетит ли массив или строка, но нужен массив, то можно воспользоваться проверками типа **[is_array](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.is-array.php)** (определяет, является ли переменная массивом), **[in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php)** (проверяет, присутствует ли в массиве значение), **[isset](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php)** (определяет, была ли установлена переменная значением, отличным от null)

```
$string = "string";
$array = array('port' => 'the_port');

if (is_array($string) && isset($string['port'])) {
    // Всё отлично, мы никогда не попадём сюда
    echo $string['port'];
}

if (is_array($array) && isset($array['port'])) {
    // Ok!
    echo $array['port']; // the_port
}

if (is_array($array) && isset($array['unset_key'])) {
    // Всё отлично, мы никогда не попадём сюда
    echo $array['unset_key'];
}

// Аналогично вышенаписанному, но с применением array_key_exists
if (is_array($array) && array_key_exists('port', $array)) {
    // Ok!
    echo $array['port']; // the_port
}
```

---

##### ### Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Параметр, передаваемый в функцию `count()`, должен быть исчисляемым/то что можно посчитать. Обычно это массив.

Вероятная проблема заключается в том, что было передано скалярное значение, такое как строка или целое число, или объект, который не реализует интерфейс `Countable`. Использование `var_dump()` для рассматриваемой переменной может показать, так ли это.

Answer (score 2):

##### ### Fatal error: Call to a member function ... on a non-object

Происходит обычно в случае `xyz->method()`, где `xyz` по какой-то причине не является объектом, как ожидалось, и, следовательно, этот `method` не может быть вызван.
Нужно убедиться, что объект на самом деле является объектом, прежде чем вызывать его методы. Т.е. в примере выше нужно быть уверенным,
что `xyz` - это объект, а не, например, `null` (наиболее часто встречается именно это) или `false`.

Как пример:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('invalid query', ...);
$statement->execute(...);
```

В приведенном примере запрос не может быть подготовлен, и `prepare()` вернёт `false`. Как следствие будет происходить попутка вызвать метод `execute()` у булевого типа, а не у объекта.

Выясните, **почему** функция вернула логическое значение вместо объекта. Например, проверьте объект `$pdo` на предмет последней произошедшей ошибки. Подробности того, как отлаживать это, будут зависеть от того, как обрабатываются ошибки для конкретной рассматриваемой функции/объекта/класса. Чаще всего ошибка возникает потому, что в коде отсутствуют проверки на наличие ошибок.

---

Другая проблема может заключаться в условном создании объекта и последующей попытке вызвать метод вне этого условного блока. Например

```
if ($someCondition) {
    $myObj = new MyObj();
}
// ...
$myObj->someMethod();
```

Смотрите наличие этой переменной выше по коду и в правильной области видимости!

---

##### ### Fatal error: Call to undefined function XXX

Происходит, когда происходит вызов функции, которая еще не определена. Распространенные причины: отсутствие расширений, неподключенный файл с функциями (через `include`/`require`), условное объявление функции (см. пример ниже), объявлении функции в функциях или просто из-за опечаток.

Условное объявление функции:

```
$someCondition = false;
if ($someCondition === true) {
    function fn() {
        return 1;
    }
}
echo fn(); // Ошибка, т.к. условие никогда не выполнится
```

Объявление функции в функции

```
function createFn() {
    function fn() {
        return 1;
    }
}
echo fn(); // Ошибка, т.к. другая область видимости
```

**Примечание:** последующие вызовы `createFn()` вызовут ошибку о повторном объявлении существующей функции.

---

Также можно увидеть эту ошибку для встроенной функции PHP. Можно попробовать найти функцию в **[официальном руководстве](http://php.net/manual/en/funcref.php)** и проверить, к какому «расширению» (модулю PHP) оно принадлежит и какие версии PHP его поддерживают. В случае отсутствия расширения - нужно установить его и включить его в `php.ini`.

В случае, если функция находится в другом файле - не забудьте его подключить перед использованием функции

В случае опечатки - исправьте опечатку %)

---

##### ### Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class *[class name]*

а также

##### ### Fatal error: Cannot redeclare *[function name]*

Это означает, что вы либо дважды используете одно и то же имя функции/класса и нужно переименовать одну/один из них, либо это потому, что использовали `require` или `include`, где должны использовать `require_once` или `include_once`.

Когда класс или функция объявляются в PHP, они неизменяемы и не могут быть позже объявлены с новым значением.

Пример:

*class.php*

```
<?php

class MyClass {
    public function doSomething() { // что-то тут }
}
```

*index.php*

```
<?php

function doStuff() {
   require 'class.php';
   $obj = new MyClass;
   $obj->doSomething();
}

doStuff();
doStuff();
```

Второй вызов `doStuff()` вызовет указанную выше ошибку. Изменив `require` на `require_once`, мы можем быть уверены, что файл, содержащий определение `MyClass`, будет загружен только один раз, и ошибки можно будет избежать.

---

Не лишним будет использовать автозагрузку, и такие стандарты, как **[PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)** (стандарт по автозагрузке). или даже устаревший PSR-0, в значительной степени избавляют от необходимости использовать `require`/`include` самостоятельно (за исключением нескольких странных крайних случаев).

См. также **[Автозагрузка классов с помощью Composer.](https://klisl.com/composer_autoload.html)**, **[Автозагрузка классов с помощью Composer2](https://webformyself.com/avtozagruzka-klassov-s-composer-v-php/)**, **[Автозагрузка классов с помощью Composer3](https://ru.hexlet.io/courses/php-introduction-to-oop/lessons/autoloading/theory_unit)**

---

##### ### Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Обычно это происходит при использовании функции напрямую с `empty`

```
if (empty(is_null(null))) {
    echo 'empty';
}
```

Это связано с тем, что **[empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)** - это языковая конструкция, а не функция. Её нельзя вызвать с выражением в качестве аргумента в версиях PHP до 5.5. До PHP 5.5 аргумент для `empty()` должен быть *variable* (то есть переменной), но в PHP 5.5+ допускается произвольное выражение (например, возвращаемое значение функции).

Не смотря на своё название, `empty` на самом деле не проверяет, является ли переменная «пустой». Она проверяет существует ли переменная или её значение равно `false`.
Выражения (такие как `is_null (null)` в примере) всегда будут считаться существующими, поэтому здесь `empty` только проверяет, равно ли оно `false`. Можно заменить здесь `empty()` на `!`, например

```
if (! is_null (null))
```

или явно сравнить с `false`, например

```
if (is_null (null) == false)
```

Answer (score 0):

##### ### Fatal error: Declaration of AAA::BBB() must be compatible with that of CCC::BBB()

Происходит при наследовании (или использовании трейтов), когда в методе в классе наследнике сигнатура метода отличается от класса родителя.
Пример в базовом классе есть метод:

```
function test($arg1, $arg2 = null)
```

а в наследнике

```
function test($arg1, $arg2, $arg3 = null)
```

То есть уже три аргумента, вместо двух. Или типы аргументов поменялись (хотя бы у одного). Например у `arg2` в первом случае был тип `int`, а во втором - `string`;

---

##### ### Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

**[`$this` -  это специальная переменная в PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.basics)**, которой нельзя ничего присваивать.
Если к ней обращаются в контексте, где её не существует, выдается эта фатальная ошибка.

Возможные моменты возникновения:

1. Если не статический метод вызывается из статического контекста. Пример:

   ```
    class Foo {
       protected $var;
       public function __construct($var) {
           $this->var = $var;
       }

       public static function bar () {
           // ^^^^^^
           echo $this->var;
           //   ^^^^^
       }
    }

    Foo::bar();
   ```

**Как исправить:** еще раз просмотрите свой код, `$this` может использоваться только в контексте объекта и никогда не должен использоваться в статическом методе. Кроме того, статический метод не должен обращаться к не статическому свойству. Используйте `self::$static_property` для доступа к статическому свойству.

2. Если код из метода класса был скопирован в обычную функцию или куда-либо ещё вне метода *и* при этом забыли убрать слово `$this`.

**Как исправить:** Просмотрите код и замените `$this` другой переменной подстановки.

---

##### ### Fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to a string

Это означает, что вы не исполняете/не вызываете свою анонимную функцию (или замыкание), а пытаетесь отправить в поток вывода через `echo`/`print`/`var_dump`/и т.д. саму функцию, а не результат выполнения.

Примеры:

Стрелочная функция

```
$fn = fn($x = 42) => $x;
echo $fn; // <--- Должно было быть echo $fn()  т.е. необходимы круглые скобки
```

или анонимная функция:

```
echo function($x = 42) { return $x; }; // должно быть echo (function($x = 42) { return $x; })(2);
```

Чтобы устранить эту ошибку, необходимо выполнить функцию (как в примере выше `echo $fn()` вместо `echo $fn` или `echo (function($x = 42) { return $x; })(30);` вместо `echo function($x = 42) { return $x; };`.
Последний синтаксис называется **[IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression)** (Immediately Invoked Function Expression - функция, которая выполняется сразу же после того, как она была определена.). Она была добавлена в PHP7

---

##### ### Fatal error: Undefined class constant

Эта ошибка означает, что вы пытались использовать несуществующую **[константу класса](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.constants.php)**. В отличие от других «неопределенных» уведомлений и предупреждений - это фатальная ошибка и скрипт немедленно останавливается.

В первую очередь следует проверить типографские ошибки. Опечатки, регистр. Нужно убедиться, что константа определена в классе и вызывается с использованием соответствующего пространства имен. Убедиться также, что все соответствующие файлы были подключены.

Один из вариантов проблемы:

```
class Test {   
    public statiс $myVar;

    public static function getSomething() {
      return 111;
    }  
}

echo Test::myVar;
echo Test::getSomething;
```

В данном случае будет ошибка и на `myVar` и на `getSomething`, т.к. к статическому свойству надо обращаться `::$myVar` а методу `::getSomething()`. А в текущем контексте `myVar` и `getSomething` получаются всего лишь непонятными константами

---

##### ### Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: some_function(): Argument #1 must be of type XXX, YYY given

В данном случае ошибка говорит о том, что код попытался вызвать `some_function()` и передал неправильный тип данных в качестве одного из аргументов. Например:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

function multiply(int $x, int $y) { 
    return $x * $y; 
}

echo multiply("3", 4);
```

Поскольку первый аргумент вызываемой функции имеет скалярный тип `int`, а вызов находится в файле, в котором включены строгие типы (`stict_types = 1`), при передаче ему тип "строка" возникает ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: multiply(): Argument #1 ($x) must be of type integer, string given in...

Понятно, что нужно чинить, чтобы в функцию приходил верный тип.

Answer (score 0):

##### ### Notice: Array to string conversion

Происходит при попытки вывести массив как строку. Обычно это происходит, когда применяется функция `echo` к массиву или конкатенируется массив в строке.

```
$arr = array('foo', 'bar');    
echo $arr;  // Notice: Array to string conversion
$str = 'Something, ' . $arr;  // Notice: Array to string conversion
```

Массив не может быть просто выведен через `echo` или объединен со строкой, потому что результат не определен должным образом.
Вероятно, вы хотели сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
echo $arr[0];  // Выведет: foo
$str = 'Something ' . join(', ', $arr); // Выведет: Something, foo, bar
```

Или сделать цикл по массиву:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "array $key = $value";        
}

// Выведет: 
// array 0 = foo
// array 1 = bar
```

Если это уведомление появляется там, где не ожидаете, это означает, что переменная, которую вы считали строкой, на самом деле является массивом. Это означает, что в вашем коде есть ошибка, которая превращает эту переменную в массив вместо ожидаемой строки.

---

##### ### Notice: Trying to get property of non-object error

Происходит при попытке обращения к свойству объекта, когда объекта нет.

Типичный пример:

```
$users = json_decode('[{"name": "hakre"}]');
echo $users->name; # Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

В примере выше `$users` является массивом (а не объектом) и не имеет никаких свойств. А вот элементы массива - объекты. И обращение `$users[0]->name` возымело бы эффект.

Это похоже на доступ к несуществующему индексу или ключу массива (см. **[Notice: Undefined Index](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1364430/191482)**).

Этот пример сильно упрощен. Чаще всего такое уведомление сигнализирует о непроверенном возвращаемом значении, например когда библиотека возвращает `NULL`, если объект не существует или просто неожиданное значение, которое не является объектом (например, в результате `Xpath`, структуры *JSON* с неожиданным форматом, *XML* с неожиданным форматом и т. д.), но код (точнее разработчик) не проверяет наличие такого состояния (что json,xml и пр. могут быть некорректными).

Поскольку эти не-объекты часто обрабатываются дальше, часто происходит фатальная ошибка при вызове метода этого объекта и возникает **[Fatal error: Call to a member function ... on a non-object](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1364103/191482)**, которая останавливает работу скрипта в том числе.

Этого можно легко предотвратить, проверив условия ошибки и/или соответствие переменной ожидаемому. Пример **DOMXPath**:

```
$result  = $xpath->query("//*[@id='detail-sections']/div[1]");
$divText = $result->item(0)->nodeValue; # Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

Тут происходит попытка обратиться к свойству (полю) `nodeValue` первого элемента, хотя проверки на то, существует ли он в коллекции `$result` не было.
Вместо этого стоит сделать код более явным, назначив переменные объектам, с которыми работает код:

```
$result  = $xpath->query("//*[@id='detail-sections']/div[1]");
$div     = $result->item(0);
$divText = "-/-";

if (is_object($div)) {
    $divText = $div->nodeValue;
}

echo $divText;
```

Answer (score 0):

##### ### Notice: Undefined Index ( Undefined array key  >= PHP8.0 )

а также

##### ### Undefined offset

Происходит при попытке обратиться по ключу массива, которого нет в массиве.

Типичный пример:

```
$data = array('foo' => '42', 'bar');
echo $data['spinach']; // Undefined index: spinach
echo $data[1]; // Undefined offset: 1
```

И `spinach` и `1` не существуют и вызовут уведомление. Но немного разные. `Undefined offset` означает, что есть пустой ключ массива, происходит обращение по **числовому** индексу в массиве, которого нет.
Самый типичный пример:

```
$arr = array('Felix','Jon','Java');

// Будет "Undefined offset" т.к. нумерация начинается с 0, 
// и будут индексы 0,1,2, а обращение идёт к индексу 3    
echo $arr[3];
```

Нужно убедиться, что индекс или ключ существует как таковой или до доступа по нему.

Нужно исправить ошибку в программе, чтобы эти индексы действительно существовали, когда это ожидается.
Или нужно проверить, что существуют нужные индексы используя **[array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-key-exists.php)** или **[empty](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php)**.
Как пример

```
$data = array('foo' => '42', 'bar');

if (array_key_exists('spinach', $data)) {
    echo $data['spinach'];
} else {
    echo 'Нет ключа "spinach" в массиве';
}
```

Как пример ещё: `preg_match` если совпадений не найдено - `$match` вернёт пустой массив. Но если не проверить и думать, что там всегда будет значение, то можно увидеть эту ошибку

```
preg_match($regex,$content,$matches)
echo $matches[0]; Undefined offset: 0   так как совпадений не нашлось
```

---

##### ### Notice: Uninitialized string offset: XXX

Ошибка возникает когда, скорее всего, идёт попытка перебрать в цикле строку по символам  или найти значение в массиве с несуществующим ключом.

Пример, цикл по строке

```
$string = 'ABCD'; 
for ($i=0, $len = strlen($string); $i <= $len; $i++){
    echo "$string[$i] \n"; 
}

// На выходе будет
A
B
C
D
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 4 in XXX on line X
```

Будет показана ошибка потому, что длина строки - 4 символа, а цикл написан от 0 до 4 **включительно**, то есть 5 итераций.

---

#### ### Notice: Use of undefined constant XXX - assumed 'XXX'

или  в >=PHP7.2:

##### ### Warning: Use of undefined constant XXX - assumed 'XXX' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Это уведомление появляется, когда в коде используется токен, который кажется константой, но константа с таким именем не определена.

Одна из наиболее частых причин появления этого уведомления - отсутствие кавычек в строке, используемой в качестве ключа ассоциативного массива:

```
// Неверно
echo $array[key];

// Верно
echo $array['key'];
```

Другой распространенной причиной является отсутствие перед именем переменной знака `$` (доллар):

```
// Неверно
echo varName;

// Верно
echo $varName;
```

Или, возможно, неправильно написали какую-то другую константу или ключевое слово:

```
// Неверно
$foo = fasle;

// Верно
$foo = false;
```

Это также может быть признаком того, что необходимое расширение или библиотека PHP отсутствует, когда происходит попытка получить доступ к константе, определенной этой библиотекой.

Answer (score 0):

##### ### Strict Standards: Non-static method *[<class>::<method>]* should not be called statically

Происходит при попытке вызвать не статический метод в классе в таком форме, как если бы он был статическим. (А также при включенном флаге `E_STRICT` в настройках `error_reporting()`)

Поясняющий пример:

```
class HTML {
   public function br() { // метод br НЕ статический!
      echo '<br>';
   }
}

HTML::br(); // <--- два двоеточия должны быть только для вызова статики!     
// или     
$html = new HTML();
$html::br(); // <--- два двоеточия должны быть только для вызова статики!
```

Конечно, можно избежать этой ошибки, не добавляя `E_STRICT` в `error_reporting(), например

```
 error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_STRICT);
```

Но лучше программировать правильно, чем не правильно!))

Решение состоит в том, чтобы определить вашу предполагаемую статическую функцию как фактическую статическую или или вызвать из контекста:

```
// решение 1
public static function br() {
    echo '<br>';
}

// решение 2
$html = new HTML();
$html->br();
```

Конечно нужно смотреть на свой контекст и, возможно, переписать класс под правильную логику и вызовы методов.

---

##### ### Warning: function() expects parameter XXX to be boolean (or integer, string, etc) , YYY given

Если в функцию передается параметр неправильного типа, а PHP не может преобразовать его автоматически, выдается это предупреждение.
Это предупреждение указывает, какой параметр является проблемой и какой тип данных ожидается.

- `expects` - ожидается
- `given` - то, что подаётся на вход
- `parameter X` - это какой по счёту параметр

Решение: измените указанный параметр на правильный тип данных. Пример:

```
echo substr(["foo"], 23);
```

Отобразится ошибка::

> PHP Warning:  substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

**Ожидается** что в первый параметр дадут тип "строка", но в реале **дан на вход** - тип "массив".

---

##### ### Deprecated: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated

До версии PHP 7.4.0 доступ к смещениям (offset) строк и элементам массива можно было получить с помощью фигурных скобок `{}`:

```
$string = 'abc';
echo $string{0};  // a

$array = [1, 2, 3];
echo $array{0};  // 1
```

С PHP 7.4.0 это устарело и отображает ошибку выше

Необходимо использовать квадратные скобки `[]` для доступа к строковым смещениям и элементам массива:

```
$string = 'abc';
echo $string[0];  // a

$array = [1, 2, 3];
echo $array[0];  // 1
```