# Почему возникает такая ошибка?

Tags: php

Написал функцию, которая распечатывает многомерный массив:

```
function printArray(array $arr){
    foreach($arr as $key=>$var){
        if(is_array($var)){
             foreach($var as $k=>$v){
                echo "$k  $v".PHP_EOL;
             }
        }
        echo "$key => $var".PHP_EOL;
    }
}

printArray([0,[1,1.1,1.2,1.3],2,3,4]);
```

Выводит такой результат:

```
0 => 0
0  1
1  1.1
2  1.2
3  1.3
PHP Warning:  Array to string conversion in /home/alex/BranderPHPcourse/lesson6/task3.php on line 14
1 => Array
2 => 2
3 => 3
4 => 4
```

Подскажите пожалуйста почему возникает такая ошибка?

Comment: Потому что вы привели нам неверный код для вызова функции. Вы, судя по результату, передаете массив с массивом внутри, а в коде выше у вас обычный массив.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что означает эта ошибка? (parse, syntax, warning, fatal)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1364090/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-parse-syntax-warning-fatal)

Comment: Да. Точно. Тестировал с одномерным массивом. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: Потому что когда $var - массив, вы всё равно вызываете echo "$key => $var", и это вызывает предупреждение о конверсии массива в строку. Оберните эту строку в else, либо добавьте continue в конце if чтобы закончить цикл.

Answer (score 0):

В коде упущен блок `else` после проверки переменной `$var` на массив. Из-за этого, даже в случае если `$var` будет массивом, код `echo "$key => $var".PHP_EOL;` будет выполняться. Использование переменной типа "массив" как строки даёт такое предупреждение.