# При открытии http://localhost/wordpress/ выдаёт Fatal error

Tags: wordpress, xampp

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "‘" in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php(17): require() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php on line 13

[image: код wp blog header]

Comment: Кое что изменил, и теперь только эта проблема Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "‘" in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php on line 17

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что означает эта ошибка? (parse, syntax, warning, fatal)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1364090/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-parse-syntax-warning-fatal)

Comment: @noob, редактор позволяет вставить форматированный код..
Приложите его, и мы поможем разобраться

Comment: странные у вас кавычки в коде