# Что здесь не так? Рассчитать сумму цифр числа

Tags: php

```
$n;
$sum = 0;

if(isset($_POST['number'])) {
    $n = strval($_POST['number']);
    numeric();
    echo 'Сумма чисел: ' . $sum;
}
else {
    echo 'Введите число';
}

function numeric() {
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($n); $i++) {
        $sum += $n[$i];
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

Ошибки:

Warning: Undefined variable $n in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\task_01\base.php on line 41

Deprecated: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\task_01\base.php on line 41

Warning: Undefined variable $sum in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\task_01\base.php on line 44

У меня есть рабочий вариант этой задачи, но просто интересно, почему именно этот не работает, не могу понять.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: в ошибках же написано, что не так. Почитайте про область видимости переменных. А строчка ``numeric();`` в этом коде фактически ничего не делает. Результат функции нужно куда-то присвоить.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что означает эта ошибка? (parse, syntax, warning, fatal)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1364090/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-parse-syntax-warning-fatal)

Comment: @Эникейщик, действительно, проблема была связана с областями видимости. Помогло, когда сделал обе переменных глобальными.