# В чем проблема? Ошибки в разных местах. Как поймать?

Tags: php, curl, pdo

Написал парсер который циклично обходит страницы и парсит с них разную информацию кладя в разные таблицы бд.
По отдельности все куски кода работают хорошо, но когда запускаю цикл, то начинаются ошибки в разных местах все время.
По логам понятно, что иногда не доходят данные до переменных, они как раз парсятся с страницы сайта с помощью phpQuery, получается curl уходит в ошибку или сам сайт выдает 404(или другую), хотя запросов и не так много шлется. Парсер работает через прокси tor socks. По отдельности куски кода так же хорошо подключаются к сайту и парсят его.

Как отловить в какой момент и что именно ломает скрипт?

```
[Sat Apr 16 03:33:02.423867 2022] [php7:error] [pid 35804] [client 127.0.0.1:11749] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'reg' at row 1 in /var/www/html/index.php:195\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/index.php(195): PDOStatement->execute()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 195
[Sat Apr 16 03:39:51.512165 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 35803] [client 127.0.0.1:11762] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 48
[Sat Apr 16 03:40:21.545378 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 35803] [client 127.0.0.1:11762] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 74
[Sat Apr 16 03:42:21.950255 2022] [php7:error] [pid 35803] [client 127.0.0.1:11762] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'sh_id' cannot be null in /var/www/html/index.php:105\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/index.php(105): PDOStatement->execute()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 105
[Sat Apr 16 04:26:41.858463 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 35889] [client 127.0.0.1:23783] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 48
[Sat Apr 16 04:26:42.732014 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 35889] [client 127.0.0.1:23783] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 74
[Sat Apr 16 04:26:43.955993 2022] [php7:error] [pid 35889] [client 127.0.0.1:23783] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'sh_id' cannot be null in /var/www/html/index.php:105\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/index.php(105): PDOStatement->execute()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 105
[Sat Apr 16 04:29:08.056854 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 40659] [client 127.0.0.1:23791] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 48
[Sat Apr 16 04:29:08.384146 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 40659] [client 127.0.0.1:23791] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 74
[Sat Apr 16 04:29:08.764910 2022] [php7:error] [pid 40659] [client 127.0.0.1:23791] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'sh_id' cannot be null in /var/www/html/index.php:105\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/index.php(105): PDOStatement->execute()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 105
[Sat Apr 16 04:36:42.681118 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 35805] [client 127.0.0.1:23745] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 174
[Sat Apr 16 04:36:42.681190 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 35805] [client 127.0.0.1:23745] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 175
[Sat Apr 16 04:36:42.681198 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 35805] [client 127.0.0.1:23745] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 176
[Sat Apr 16 04:36:42.681203 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 35805] [client 127.0.0.1:23745] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 178
[Sat Apr 16 04:36:42.684034 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 35805] [client 127.0.0.1:23745] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 174
[Sat Apr 16 04:36:42.684054 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 35805] [client 127.0.0.1:23745] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 175
[Sat Apr 16 04:36:42.684060 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 35805] [client 127.0.0.1:23745] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 176
[Sat Apr 16 04:36:42.684065 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 35805] [client 127.0.0.1:23745] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 178
[Sat Apr 16 04:36:42.685898 2022] [php7:error] [pid 35805] [client 127.0.0.1:23745] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'reg' at row 1 in /var/www/html/index.php:196\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/index.php(196): PDOStatement->execute()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 196
[Sat Apr 16 04:41:07.355879 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 35804] [client 127.0.0.1:23750] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 71 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 49
[Sat Apr 16 04:41:08.518028 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 35804] [client 127.0.0.1:23750] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 75
[Sat Apr 16 04:41:09.186684 2022] [php7:error] [pid 35804] [client 127.0.0.1:23750] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'sh_id' cannot be null in /var/www/html/index.php:106\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/index.php(106): PDOStatement->execute()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 106
```

Comment: Есть конечно нюанс. что данные не проверяются при парсинге. То есть возможно на странице которая попадает в цикл просто нету этих данных и переменные становятся пустые, но опять как поймать на какой странице это случилось? В ручную перебирать, больше 500 страниц надо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что означает эта ошибка? (parse, syntax, warning, fatal)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1364090/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-parse-syntax-warning-fatal)

Comment: Вопрос в том как поймать цикл в котором ошибка, а не что значит это. Чтобы избежать в будущем таких ошибок которые неизвестно. Тут я сам описал, что в переменную не попадает строка из-за того, что не было, что попадало под парсинг.

Comment: попробуйте try catch в цикле, для перехвата ошибки, и вывода дополнительной информации, например содержимое распарсиваемой страницы