# Как добавить все условия в одну переменную в php?

Tags: php, mysql

Я вывожу из базы MYSQL жанры, а чтобы их перевести на русский - я делаю вот такую конструкцию:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM genres_posts WHERE game_id = '$id' limit 10");
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
if ($row["url_genre_name"] == 'ekshen') {echo '<li>Экшен</li>';}
if ($row["url_genre_name"] == 'simulyator') {echo '<li>Симулятор</li>';}
if ($row["url_genre_name"] == 'strategiya') {echo '<li>Стратегия</li>';}
if ($row["url_genre_name"] == 'sport') {echo '<li>Спорт</li>';}
if ($row["url_genre_name"] == 'priklyuchenie') {echo '<li>Приключение</li>';}
if ($row["url_genre_name"] == 'rolevaya-igra') {echo '<li>Ролевая игра</li>';}
if ($row["url_genre_name"] == 'golovolomka') {echo '<li>Головоломка</li>';}
if ($row["url_genre_name"] == 'indi') {echo '<li>Инди</li>';}
}
```

Можно ли как то сделать так, чтобы загнать все это в одну переменную, и чтобы я вставлял, скажем вот так и выводился жанр с переводом? Как это можно реализовать? У меня по коду много мест, куда нужно вставлять такую конструкцию и код превращается в гору этого текста.

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM genres_posts WHERE game_id = '$id' limit 10");
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $genre;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо сделать мапу и обращаться по ключу к ней:

```
$map = ['sport' => 'Спорт', 'indi' => 'Инди', и т.д.];
echo "<li>{$map[$row['url_genre_name']]}</li>";
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: in /var/www/www-root/data/www/site.ru/game.php on line 134. Это строка echo "<li>{$map[$row['url_genre_name']]}</li>";

Comment: Если вместо $row['url_genre_name'] ставлю напрямую жанр типа sport - то все выводит.

Comment: Значит у тебя в $row нет ключа url_genre_name. либо в map нет нужного  ключа....... (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1364430/191482)   +  отладка https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482

Comment: есть, если ставлю вывод просто echo $row['url_genre_name'] - то выводится неск значений sport, indi и т.д.

Comment: ................"либо в map нет нужного ключа".............

Comment: там я перечислил все

Comment: ....значит не всё.

Comment: ошибка конкретная. если не веришь - ссылки выше о том что означает эта ошибка и как продебажить свой код чтобы увидеть что где не так

Comment: Прошу прощения, ошибка была в том, что я поставил эту строку после } вывода из базы :) Все работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

В PHP 8 для этого можно использовать новое выражение `match`

```
echo '<li>',
match($row['url_genre_name']){
    'ekshen' => 'Экшен',
    'simulyator' => 'Симулятор',
    'strategiya' => 'Стратегия',
    'sport' => 'Спорт',
    'priklyuchenie' => 'Приключение',
    'rolevaya-igra' => 'Ролевая игра',
    'golovolomka' => 'Головоломка',
    'indi' => 'Инди'
},
'</li>';
```