# PHP parse/syntax errors; Ошибки Unexpected XXX и как решить их

Tags: php, обработка-ошибок, php-faq

Часто программисты допускают ошибки. Могут возникать ошибки синтаксиса. Например:

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in index.php on line 20

Неожиданный символ *не всегда* является настоящим виновником. Но номер строки дает приблизительное представление о том, с чего начать поиск.

Всегда смотрите на **контекст кода**. Синтаксическая ошибка часто кроется в упомянутых **или** в *предыдущих строках кода*. Сравните свой код с примерами синтаксиса из руководства.

---

Дополнительные ссылки для поиска ошибок:

- **[Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482)**
- **[Что означает эта ошибка? (parse, syntax, warning, fatal)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1364090/191482)**

---

В ответах ниже обобщены распространенные ошибки, **найдите ошибку в списке ниже и перейдите к ответу с её описанием.**

- **[Общие шаги для устранения синтаксических ошибок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1437803/191482)**
- [Unexpected T_STRING 
   Unexpected identifier "xxx" 


  Unexpected T_VARIABLE 
   Unexpected '$varname' (T_VARIABLE)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1437805/191482)
- [Unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING 
   Unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE 


  Unexpected $end / Unexpected end of file 


  Unexpected T_FUNCTION](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1437806/191482)
- [Unexpected `{`
  Unexpected `}`
  Unexpected `{`, expecting `(` 
   Unexpected `(`
  Unexpected `)`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1437807/191482)
- [Unexpected `[`
  Unexpected `]`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1438134/191482)
- [Unexpected T_IF 
   Unexpected T_FOREACH 
   Unexpected T_FOR 
   Unexpected T_WHILE 
   Unexpected T_DO 
   Unexpected T_PRINT 
   Unexpected T_ECHO 


  Unexpected T_LNUMBER](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1445083/191482)
- [Unexpected ? 


  Unexpected continue (T_CONTINUE)
  Unexpected continue (T_BREAK)
  Unexpected continue (T_RETURN) 


  Unexpected '=' 


  Unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM 


  Unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR 


  Unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW 


  Unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR  
   Unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1445087/191482)
- [Unexpected T_IS_EQUAL 

  Unexpected T_IS_GREATER_OR_EQUAL 

  Unexpected T_IS_IDENTICAL 

  Unexpected T_IS_NOT_EQUAL 

  Unexpected T_IS_NOT_IDENTICAL 

  Unexpected T_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL 

  Unexpected `<` 

  Unexpected `>`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1461092/191482)
- [Unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) 
   Unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE) 
   Unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED) 
   Unexpected 'final' (T_FINAL)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1487761/191482)
- [Unexpected T_STATIC 

  Unexpected T_CLASS 

  Unexpected 'use' (T_USE) 

  Unexpected T_DNUMBER](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1487770/191482)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Общее о синтаксических ошибках

---

##### ### Заметка:

1. Если ваш *браузер* отображает сообщения об ошибках, такие как "SyntaxError: illegal character", то это на самом деле связано не с *PHP*, а с *Javascript* и синтаксическими ошибками в нём
2. **Синтаксические ошибки, возникающие в коде vendor:** если синтаксическая ошибка возникла после установки или обновления пакета vendor'а - это может быть связано с несовместимостью версии *PHP*, поэтому проверьте версию vendor'а.
   и требования к настройке вашей платформы.
3. Используйте *IDE*, например *PHPStorm*, который всегда подскажет, что с кодом что-то не так. Обращайте внимание на подсказки:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Иногда возникают ошибки из-за лишних символов в начале файла, в частности BOM. Убедитесь, что файл сохранён в UTF-8 без BOM. (если нужен именно utf8)
5. Если ваш веб-сайт просто пустой с белым экраном, то, как правило, причиной является синтаксическая ошибка. Включите их отображение с помощью **[этой инструкции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701145/191482)**

##### ### Как интерпретировать ошибки парсера

Типичное сообщение об ошибке синтаксиса:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected **T_STRING**, expecting **'`;`'** in *file.php* on **line** *217*

(Ошибка синтаксического анализа: синтаксическая ошибка, неожиданный **T_STRING**, ожидалось **'`;`'** в файле *file.php* в **строке** *217*)

Тут указано *возможное* место синтаксической ошибки. См. упомянутые **имя файла** и **номер строки**.

**[Токен](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/tokens.php)**, такой как `T_STRING`, объясняет, какой символ синтаксический анализатор/токенизатор не смог окончательно обработать. Однако это не обязательно является причиной синтаксической ошибки. Поэтому важно изучить **предыдущие строки кода**. Часто синтаксические ошибки - это ошибки, произошедшие ранее. Номер строки ошибки - это именно то место, где синтаксический анализатор окончательно отказался от обработки всего этого, а не точная линия ошибки

Answer (score 3):

##### Unexpected T_STRING

##### Unexpected identifier "xxx"

Означает, что был обнаружен необработанный идентификатор. Это может быть разное: от "голых слов" до оставшихся констант или имен функций, забытых строк без кавычек или любого простого текста. Примерные проблемы:

1. #### Строки с неверными кавычками

   Любая неэкранированная и случайная кавычка `"` или `'` образует недопустимое выражение.

   ```
                 ⇓                  ⇓
   echo "<a href="http://example.com">click here</a>";
   ```

   В данном примере используются двойные кавычки в двойных. Это **неверно**. Интерпретатор "увидит" строку `"<a href="` и строку `">click here</a>"` (т.к. строки заключаются в кавычки), а что такое `http://example.com` он не поймёт.
   Важно не забывать использовать обратный слэш для экранирования `\"` двойных кавычек или `\'` одинарных кавычек - в зависимости от того, что использовалось снаружи для всей строки (**[для ознакомления со строками](https://www.php.net/language.types.string)**). Например если снаружи двойные кавычки, то внутри проще использовать одинарные, чтобы не запутаться, либо экранировать двойную. С одинарными аналогично. Ещё проще большой текст помещать в **[HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)** или **[NOWDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)**
2. #### Незакрытые строки

   Если вы пропустите закрывающую кавычку, то синтаксическая ошибка обычно возникает позже.

   ```
                                                           ⇓   тут не закрыли и поэтому интерпретатор считает, что строка идёт дальше
    echo "Some text", $a_variable, "and some runaway string ;
    success("finished");
            ⇯ и тут закрылась..... а что такое `finished");` он не знает
   ```
3. #### Кавычки, не связанные с программированием

   Обычно возникают, когда копируют текст из книги. Они могут выглядеть так:

   ```
   $text = ’Something something..’ + ”these ain't quotes”;
           ^---                  ^-- ^---               ^---
   ```
4. #### Отсутствует точка с запятой

   ```
          ⇓
   func1()
   function2();
   ```
5. #### Невидимые символы Unicode

   Если вы получили жалобу парсера T_STRING на совершенно не вызывающий подозрений код, например:

   ```
   <?php
       print 123;
   ```

   Нужно взять другой текстовый редактор. Или даже hexeditor. То, что здесь выглядит как простые пробелы и символы новой строки, может содержать невидимые константы. Такое бывает в документах с кодировкой `UTF-8 BOM` и нужно сделать кодировку `UTF-8 без BOM`
6. #### Заэкранированная кавычка

   Символ `\` имеет особое значение. Часто символ `\` применяют для экранирования в строках. Чтобы кавычка внутри строки, которая обёрнута в такие же кавычки, печаталась как есть, то её экранируют. Т.е. строка `echo "Jim said \"Hello\"";` выведет `Jim said "hello"`. Если применить последовательность `\"`, то она будет расценена как попытка экранирования кавычки. Поэтому строка ниже, выдаст ошибку

   ```
   "C:\xampp\htdocs\"
   ```

   правильно будет экранировать обратные слэши тоже:

   ```
   "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\"
   ```

---

---

##### Unexpected T_VARIABLE

##### Unexpected '$varname' (T_VARIABLE)

Означает, что есть конкретная переменная **с указаннымв ошибке именем**, которая не вписывается в текущую структуру выражения/инструкции.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибки:

1. #### Отсутствует точка с запятой

   Как правило пропущена точка с запятой, а на следующей строке идёт переменная:

   ```
          ⇓
   func1()
   $var = 1 + 2;     # parse error in line +2
   ```
2. #### Неверная конкатенация строк

   ```
                                ⇓  Пропущен знак конкатенации
   echo "Here comes the value: "  $value;
   ```
3. #### Пропущен оператор выражения

   ```
             ⇓
   echo 4 + 7 $var;
   ```
4. #### В перечислениях в массивах или функциях

   ```
                                         ⇓
   $var = array("1" => $val, $val2, $val3 $val4);

                                   ⇓
   function myfunc($param1, $param2 $param3, $param4)
   ```
5. #### В объявлении свойств классов

   В свойства можно назначать только статические значения (которые однозначно определены), но не выражения.

   ```
    class xyz {         ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ - это выражение, а не статическое значение. Непозволительно
        public $value = $_GET["input"];
   ```

   Если необходимо присвоивать переменной выражение, то это нужно делать либо в конструкторе, либо в другом каком-либо инициализирующем методе
6. #### Переменные сразу после идентификаторов

   ```
                ⇓
   $this->myFunc$VAR();
   ```
7. #### Отсутствие скобок до/после языковых конструкций if, for, foreach

   ```
          ⇓
   foreach $array as $key) {

                             ⇓
   if ($var = pdo_query($sql) {
       $result = …
   ```
8. #### Else не ожидает условий

   ```
        ⇓
   else ($var >= 0)
   ```

   тут надо либо фигурные скобки, либо применять `elseif` (если не нарушает логики)
9. #### Необходимы скобки для замыканий (closure)

   ```
                  ⇓
   function() use $var {}
   ```

   Переменные, которые передаются в замыкания всегда надо оборачивать в круглые скобки
10. #### Невидимые пробелы

    Как отмечалось ранее. Могут быть невидимые символы. Проверьте на их наличие (читайте выше ошибки **Unexpected T_STRING**)

Answer (score 1):

##### Unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

##### Unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE

Предупреждения *T_ENCAPSED…* появляются в контексте строки с **двойными кавычками**, в то время как строки *T_CONSTANT…* часто возникают в простых выражениях или операторах *PHP*.

Ошибки:

1. #### Неправильная интерполяция переменных

   ```
   echo "Here comes a $wrong['array'] access";
   ```

   Ключи массива должны быть в кавычках. Но в строках с двойными кавычками (или HEREDOC) это не так. Парсер жалуется на содержащуюся в одинарных кавычках строку.

   Можно использовать PHP2-style для написания ключей мамссивов внутри строки

   ```
   echo "This is only $valid[here] ...";
   ```

   Но лучше изучить **[фигурный синтаксис](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)**  и использовать его. Он позволяет писать ключи массива как обычно:

   ```
   echo "Use {$array['as_usual']} with curly syntax.";
   ```
2. #### Отсутствует конкатенация

   ```
                         ⇓
   echo "Hello " . WORLD  " !";
   ```
3. #### Отсутствует начальная кавычка

   ```
            ⇓
   make_url(login', 'open');
   ```
4. #### Пропущена запятая в массиве

   ```
   array(               ⇓
        "key" => "value"
        "next" => "....",
   );
   ```
5. #### Пропущена запятая в аргументах функции/метода

   ```
                             ⇓
   myfunc(123, "text", "and"   "more")
   ```
6. #### Строка закрыта слишком поздно

   ```
                                   ⇓
   mysql_evil("SELECT * FROM stuffs);
   print "'ok'";
         ⇑
   ```
7. #### Отступ в HEREDOC

   До версии 7.3 закрывающий идентификатор **должен** был находиться в самом начале новой строки. Поэтому код ниже вызовет ошибку

   ```
   $test = <<<HTML
          <link..>
      HTML;
   ⇑⇑⇑
   ```

---

---

##### Unexpected $end

##### Unexpected end of file

Ошибка означает, что код закончился, в то время как парсер ожидает больше кода. (Сообщение немного вводит в заблуждение, если понимать его буквально. Речь идет не о переменной с именем «$end», как иногда предполагают новички. Оно относится к «концу файла»). **Причина**: несовпадение количества открывающих и закрывающих фигурных скобок.

**Почти всегда** речь идет об отсутствующей закрывающей фигурной скобке `}` для закрытия предшествующих блоков кода. Это говорит о том, что синтаксический анализатор ожидает найти закрывающую скобку `}`, но на самом деле достиг конца файла.

- Используйте правильные отступы, чтобы избежать таких проблем. И вообще, в принципе, **используйте отступы и форматирование!**
- Используйте *IDE* с сопоставлением скобок, чтобы выяснить, где `}` была утеряна. Большинство *IDE* выделяют совпадающие фигурные скобки, квадратные скобки и круглые скобки. Что позволяет довольно легко проверить соответствие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Отступ в HEREDOC

До версии 7.3 закрывающий идентификатор **должен** был находиться в самом начале новой строки. Поэтому код ниже может вызывать ошибку

```
$test = <<<HTML
        <link..>
    HTML;
⇑⇑⇑
```

#### Заэкранированная кавычка

Символ `\` имеет особое значение. Часто символ `\` применяют для экранирования в строках. Чтобы кавычка внутри строки, которая обёрнута в такие же кавычки, печаталась как есть, то её экранируют. Т.е. строка `echo "Jim said \"Hello\"";` выведет `Jim said "hello"`. Если применить последовательность `\"`, то она будет расценена как попытка экранирования кавычки. Поэтому строка ниже, выдаст ошибку

```
"C:\xampp\htdocs\"
```

правильно будет экранировать обратные слэши тоже:

```
"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\"
```

С другой стороны, *PHP* обычно преобразует пути в стиле Unix (например, `"C:/xampp/htdocs/"`) в правильный путь для Windows.

#### Альтернативный синтаксис

Несколько реже вы можете увидеть эту синтаксическую ошибку при использовании альтернативного синтаксиса для блоков операторов/кодов в шаблонах. Используя `if:` и `else:` отсутствует `endif;`, например (т.е. закрывающий тег)

---

---

##### Unexpected T_FUNCTION

Может возникнуть например в версии *PHP* ниже 5.3.0, когда не было ещё анонимных функций. В некоторые функции, такие как `array_map` нужно было передать имя функции обработчика, например `$range = array_map( "name_of_function_to_call", $myArray );`. Так что минимум надо проверить версию *PHP* и проверить что именно на вход ожадает текущая функция. И принять решение: повысить версию *PHP* или переписать под старый стиль: создать отдельно функцию и во вторую передать имя первой.

Answer (score 1):

##### Unexpected `(`

Открывающие круглые скобки обычно следуют за языковыми конструкциями, такими как `if`/`foreach`/`for`/`array`/`list`, или начинают арифметическое выражение. Они синтаксически неверны после `"strings"`, предыдущих скобок `()`, одинокого `$` и в некоторых типичных контекстах объявлений. Типичные ошибки:

1. #### Выражения в параметрах объявленной функции

   ```
   function calcRating($value, $expires = time() + 90000) {
   ```

   Параметры в объявлении функции могут быть только литеральными значениями или константными выражениями. То есть выражение `time() + 90000` нельзя использовать в качестве дефолтного значения параметра функциию. Тем не менее **при вызове функции** можно свободно использовать выражение:

   ```
   myFunction(1 + anotherFunc() * 2)
   ```
2. #### Выражения в свойствах класса

   Как и ошибка выше, нельзя применять выражения для свойств класса, т.е.

   ```
   class xyz {                   
       var $default = someFunction("xyz_default");
   ```

   Если необходимо что-то вычислить, то данные вычисления/выражения стОит помеестить в конструктор класса.

   Единственное, *PHP 7* позволяет  написать `public $property = 1 + 2 + 3;`. Но это посзволительно, т.к., по сути, это выражение с константными значениями, не вычисляемое "на лету".
3. #### isset(()), empty, key, next, current

   И `isset()` и `empty()` являются встроенными языковыми конструкциями языка, а не функциями, им необходим **прямой доступ к переменной**. Если вы непреднамеренно добавите слишком много скобок, то вы создадите доп. выражение:

   ```
             ⇓
   if (isset(($_GET["id"]))) {
   ```

   Для *PHP* <= 5.4  будет ошибка `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '('`

   Для *PHP* <= 7.0 будет ошибка `Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression`

   Начиная с версии 7.0 - ошибки не будет

##### Unexpected `)`

1. #### Висячая запятая при вызове функции/метода

   ```
                 ⇓
   callfunc(1, 2, );
   ```

   В новых версиях языка позволены висячие запятые при нициализации массивов или списков (а также в объявлении функций/методов), но не при вызове функций/методов
2. #### Незавершённые выражения

   Например если забыли в арифметическом выражении, то синтаксический анализатор сдается. Потому что он не знает как интерпретировать это:

   ```
                  ⇓
   $var = 2 * (1 + );
   ```

   Но если забыли закрывающую скобку вдобавок, то получите жалобу о неожиданной точке с запятой.
3. #### Foreach as `constant`

   Если забыть добавить доллар к переменной:

   ```
                      ↓    ⇓
   foreach ($array as wrong) {
   ```

   PHP здесь иногда говорит, что вместо этого ожидался `->` или `?->`. Поскольку `class->variable` мог бы удовлетворить ожидаемому выражению.

##### Unexpected `{`

Фигурные скобки `{` и `}` окружают блоки кода. И синтаксические ошибки о них обычно указывают на какую-то неправильную вложенность.

1. #### Unmatched subexpressions in an `if` (Несовпадающие подвыражения) в `if`

   Чаще всего несбалансированные `(` и `)` являются причиной, если парсер жалуется на открывающуюся фигурную скобку `{`, которая появляется слишком рано. Простой пример:

   ```
                                ⇓
   if (($x == $y) && (2 == true) {
   ```

   Необходимо посчитать все открывающие и закрывающие скобки и сопоставить их количество. Также используйте *IDE*, которая помогает в этом и не пишите код без пробелов. Удобочитаемость имеет значение.
2. #### { and } в выражениях

   Нельзя оборачивать выражения в скобки.

   ```
              ⇓
   $var = 5 * {7 + $x};
   ```

   Придётся выражение вынести в переменную и подставлять уже её:

   ```
   $expr = 7 + $x
   $var = 5 * $expr;
   ```

##### Unexpected `}`

Когда получаете ошибку "unexpected `}`", чаще всего означает, что закрывали блок кода слишком рано.

1. #### Последнее выражение в блоке и потеря точки с запятой

   ```
   function whatever() {
       doStuff()
   }            ⇧
   ```
2. #### Недопустимая вложенность блоков/Forgotten `{` (забытая `{` )

   Блок кода был `}` закрыт слишком рано, или забыли открытую скобку `{`:

   ```
   function doStuff() {
       if (true)    ⇦
           print "yes";
       }
   }   ⇧
   ```

   В приведенном выше фрагменте `if` не было открывающей фигурной скобки `{`. Таким образом, закрывающая `}` ниже стала излишней. И поэтому следующая закрывающая `}`, предназначенная для функции, не была связана с исходной     открывающей фигурной скобкой `{`.

##### Unexpected `{`, expecting `(`

Языковые конструкции, требующие условия/объявления **и** блока кода, вызовут эту ошибку.

1. #### Список параметров функции/метода

   ```
                    ⇓  нет скобок и параметров
   function whatever {
   }
   ```
2. #### Условные конструкции

   ```
     ⇓  нельзя писать if без какого-либо условия
   if {
   }
   ```

То же самое для частых используемых конструкций: `for`/`foreach`, `while`/`do`, etc.

Как минимум всегда **смотрите документацию**, чтобы сравнить, правильно ли вы пишите ne или иную конструкцию/функцию/метод/класс и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

##### Unexpected `[`

Часто возникает в старых версиях *PHP*. В версии  PHP >= 5.4 стал возможен сокращённый синтаксис объявления массивов

```
$php53 = array(1, 2, 3);  // Старый синтаксис
$php54 = [1, 2, 3];       // Новый синтаксис PHP >= 5.4
         ⇑
```

Разыменование массивов также с версии 5.4. Оно позволяет, например, **сразу же** обратиться к ключу массива, который вернула функция.

```
function getData() {
    return ['first' => 1, 'second' => 2];
}
getData()['first'];
         ⇑  // До версии 5.4 это невозможно
```

это же касается и встроенных функций, например `explode` и других, которые возвращают массив

Обязательно **проверьте версию PHP**

---

Другие варианты:

- Нельзя в свойствах метода сразу внести данные в ячейку массива

  ```
  protected $var["x"] = "Nope";
                ⇑⇑⇑⇑
  ```

  Если это необходимо - делайте это в конструкторе или каком-либо инициализирующием методе
- Случайно опеатались и вместо другой скобки поставили квадратную

  ```
  foreach [$a as $b)
          ⇑
  ```

  или даже

  ```
  function foobar[$a, $b, $c] {
                 ⇑
  ```
- Вы пытаетесь использовать ключевое слово `global` для члена ассоциативного массива. Это недопустимый синтаксис:

  ```
  global $var['key'];
  ```

##### Unexpected `]`

- Случайно опеатались и вместо другой скобки поставили квадратную

  ```
  foreach [$a as $b)
          ⇑
  ```
- Пытаетесь закончить массив там, где его нет:

  ```
  $var = 2];
  ```

  Часто это возникает во вложенных массивах

  ```
  $array = [1,[2,3],4,[5,6[7,[8],[9,10]],11],12]],15];
                                               ⇑
  ```

  Используйте *IDE* для сопоставления скобок и нормально форматируйте код %))

Answer (score 0):

##### Unexpected T_IF 
Unexpected T_FOREACH 
Unexpected T_FOR 
Unexpected T_WHILE 
Unexpected T_DO 
Unexpected T_ECHO

Частые проблемы с операторами `if`, `foreach`, `for`, `while`, `list`, `global`, `return`, `do`, `print`, `echo`

1. #### Точка с запятой не там

   Довольно часто пропущена точка с запятой в **предыдущей строке**

   ```
                ⇓
   $x = myfunc()
   if (true) {
   ```
2. #### Код в классе, находится вне методов

   ```
   class xyz {
       if (true) {}  <-- нельзя так! надо писать в методах!!!
       foreach ($var) {}  <-- нельзя так! надо писать в методах!!!
   ```
3. #### Используются зарезервированные ключевые слова в качестве идентификаторов

   Нельзя использовать `do`, `if` и другие языковые конструкции в качестве имён функций/методов или имён классов.
4. #### СтоИт точка с запятой вместо двоеточия (:) или фигурной скобки ({) после блока управления

   Управляющие структуры обычно заключены в фигурные скобки, но в **[альтернативном синтаксисе](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)** могут использоваться двоеточия. Если там случайно использовать точку с запятой, то преждевременно закрывается этот самый блок:

   ```
     foreach ($errors as $error); <-- должно быть  :  или  {
   ```

---

---

##### Unexpected T_LNUMBER

1. #### Недопустимые имена переменных

   Имена **[переменных](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.basics.php)** не могут начинаться с цифры. Первый символ должен быть буквенным или символом подчеркивания.

   ```
    $1   // Плохо 
    $_1  // Хорошо
   ```

   [image: *]

   - Довольно часто появляется при использовании `preg_replace`-заполнителей `"$1"` но в контексте функций непосредственно *PHP*:

     ```
       #                         ↓            ⇓  ↓
       preg_replace("/#(\w+)/e",  strtopupper($1) )
     ```

     Там, где callback - должны были быть кавычки. Однако их пропустили (P.S.  флаг `/e` устарел, но иногда он всё еще неправильно используется в `preg_replace_callback`)
   - Хотя токенизатор/парсер не допускает буквального `$1` в качестве имени переменной, можно использовать `${1}` или `${"1"}`. Это синтаксический обходной путь для нестандартных идентификаторов. (Лучше думать об этом как о поиске в локальной области. Но в целом: для таких случаев предпочитайте простые массивы!)
2. #### Обращение к нумерованному ключу объекта через стрелочку ->

   Обычно возникает в объектах типа `stdClass Object`, появляющиеся после `json_decode` без флага `true`

   ```
               ↓
        $json->0->value
   ```

   Правильно будет:

   ```
               ↓↓↓
        $json->{0}->value
   ```
3. #### Пропущены запятые в объявлении массивов

   ```
    #            ↓ ↓
    $xy = array(1 2 3);
   ```

   Или подобное, но в параметрах функции или конструкций:

   ```
   func(1, 2  3);`
             ^----

   function xy($z 2);
                 ^-----

   for ($i=2 3<$z)
            ^----
   ```

   Обычно один из знаков, таких как `;` или `,`  пропущен при разделении списка выражений.
4. #### Ошибка расстановки кавычек, несовпадение кавычек

   ```
    #                 ↓ ↓          
    echo "<td colspan="3">something bad</td>";
   ```

   Подробно описано про кавычки в [Unexpected T_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/a/#) errors.
5. #### Другие идентификаторы

   Ни функции, ни классы, ни пространства имен не могут начинаться с числа:

   ```
             ↓
    function 123shop() {
   ```

Answer (score 0):

##### Unexpected '?'

Если вы пытаетесь использовать тег `<?php` внутри другого такого же тега `<?php`*

```
$var = 'hello '<?php echo 'world'; ?>;
```

<sup>* Для PHP версий 4.3.1, 4.3.5 - 4.3.11, 4.4.0 - 4.4.1, 5.0.0 - 5.0.5, 4.4.2 - 4.4.9, 5.1.0 - 5.1.6, 5.2.0 - 5.2.17, 5.3.0 - 5.3.29, 5.4.0 - 5.4.45, 5.5.0 - 5.5.38, 5.6.0 - 5.6.40, 7.0.0 - 7.0.33, 7.1.0 - 7.1.33, 7.2.0 - 7.2.34, 7.3.0 - 7.3.31, 7.4.0 - 7.4.24</sup>

---

Если используется оператор null coalescing operator `??` в версиях *PHP* ниже, чем *PHP 7*

```
<?= $a ?? 2; // Работает в PHP 7+
<?= (!empty($a)) ? $a : 2; // Работает во всех версиях PHP
```

#### Unexpected '?', expecting variable

Аналогичная ошибка может возникнуть для типов, допускающих значение NULL, например:

```
function add(?int $sum): ?int {
```

Что снова указывает на то, что используется **устаревшая версия PHP** (то же касается CLI). Проверьте версию *PHP* через `phpinfo();`. Необходимо будет либо повысить версию, либо переписать код под старые версии, без использования нового синтаксиса

---

---

##### Unexpected 'continue' (T_CONTINUE)

Оператор `continue` используется только **внутри циклических структур** для пропуска оставшейся части текущей итерации цикла и, при соблюдении условий, начала следующей итерации.  `continue` **не возвращает значения**
Таким образом `continue` нельзя использовать в **тернарном операторе** или любом операторе, требующем возвращаемого значения (return).

##### Unexpected 'break' (T_BREAK)

То же самое касаестся `break;`. Нельзя использовать в выражениях (те, что могут вернуть значение). Используется внутри for, foreach, while, do-while или switch.

##### Unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

Если на предыдущих строках произошла синтакцическая ошибка, то при приходе к слову `return`  будет подобная ошибка. Например:

```
is ($value == null) { // Ожидалось что будет if    
    return $this->unban();
}
```

или

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users' VALUES ('', '$email', '$name', '".md5 ($password)."')" 
                                                                                       ^^^ нет знаков  );
return mysql_insert_id();
```

При данной ошибке ищите синтаксическую ошибку **раньше указанного места в тексте ошибки**, а не прямо на этой же строчке.

---

---

##### Unexpected '='

Может быть вызвано наличием недопустимых символов в имени переменной. Имена переменных **должны** соответствовать следующим правилам:

> Имена переменных соответствуют тем же правилам, что и остальные наименования в PHP. Правильное имя переменной должно начинаться с буквы или символа подчёркивания и состоять из букв, цифр и символов подчёркивания в любом количестве. Это можно отобразить регулярным выражением: ^[a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*$

> **Замечание:** Под буквами здесь подразумеваются символы a-z, A-Z и байты от 128 до 255 (0x80-0xff).

---

---

##### Unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM

T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM - это наименование для двойного двоеточия `::`  на иврите ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Происходит использование двойного двоеточия, вместо стрелочки объекта (статический вызов, вместо вызова метода в нестатическом контексте).

Например в коде указано `$cnf::getConfig($key);`, а должно быть `$cnf->getConfig($key);`

Это было возможно в ранних версиях. Возможно ошибка появилась после переноса куда-либо (например нахостинг). Поэтому проверьте версию *PHP* и либо установится такую же версию, на которой было разработано приложение, либо измените вызов свойства/метода на вызов их не в статическом виде

---

---

##### Unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

1. #### В очень старых версиях PHP (4) нельзя делать "method chaining", т.е. консрукция ниже не сработает

   ```
   $item->get_enclosure()->get_link()
   ```
2. #### В версиях ниже *PHP 5.4* нельзя вызвать метод у только что созданного объекта

   ```
   $purchaseOrder = (new PurchaseOrderFactory)->instance();
   ```

   можно вначале создать объект, а только потом вызвать у него метод:

   ```
   $purchaseFactory = new PurchaseOrderFactory;
   $purchaseOrder = $purchaseFactory->instance();
   ```

   Также нужно обратить внимание на круглые скобки, писать `new PurchaseOrderFactory->instance();` нельзя, это невалидно!
3. #### Пропущен знак доллара у переменной.

   Например написано `mysqli->query`, а должно быть `$mysqli->query`  или написано `this->transform($lessons)` а должно быть `$this->transform($lessons)`

---

---

##### Unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Причины:

1. #### Использование `=>` при описании массива, но при этом ключевое слово объявления массива было забыто:

   ```
   $statement->execute( ':login'=>$_POST['email'] );
   ```

   должно быть

   ```
   $statement->execute(array(':login' => $_POST['email']));
   ```
2. #### Пропущена запятая перед объявлением массива

   ```
   Route::post('/updateaccount'[
                              ⇑  
       'uses' => 'UserController@postSaveAccount',
       'as' => 'account.save'
   ]);
   ```

   должно быть

   ```
   Route::post('/updateaccount', [  
                               ⇑    
       'uses' => 'UserController@postSaveAccount',
       'as' => 'account.save'
   ]);
   ```
3. #### Пропущена какой-то закрывающий элемент в пересислении массива

   ```
   $saveData = array(
       'mid' => $this->_saveAsUserId,        
       'post_name' => slug($thisShow['title'],
                                             ⇑   Пропущена закрывающая скобка функции slug        
       'post_content' => $thisShow['content'],        
   );
   ```

---

---

##### Unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR
Unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND

Возникают, как правило, вследствие несовпадения открывающих и закрывающих круглых скобок. Пример

```
if(is_file($filechk1) && (is_file($filechk2))) || (is_file($dirchk1) && (is_file($dirchk2))){
                                             ⇑
    ...
}
```

или

```
if ($args == !empty && $command != 'reload'){
             ^^^^^^ Невалидно. должно быть `!empty($args)`
}
```

или

```
if(isset($_GET['test'] && strcmp($_GET['test'],'test') == 0)
                     ⇑
```

**Решение**: проверьте весь код на соответствие скобок друг другу! Если нужно, то выносите сложные конструкции в отдельные переменные, чтобы не путаться и работайте с ними. Пример

```
if (IS_REGISTRATOR() && (($params.status === 'W' || $params.status === 'D' || $params.status === 'A') && $params.remark && (($params.subres_level == 0 && ($user_info->selected_title->tid == $params.boss || $user_info->selected_title->tid == $doc_signer_tid || !$params.usertid) || $params.subres_level > 0 && $user_info->selected_title->tid == $params.usertid))) { ... }
```

этот код будет читаться легче в таком виде:

```
$docIsInWorkAcceptOrDraft = ...;
$bossHasSignerPriviledge = ...;
$userCanSign = ...;

if ($docIsInWorkAcceptOrDraft && $bossHasSignerPriviledge && $userCanSign) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Unexpected T_IS_EQUAL 
Unexpected T_IS_GREATER_OR_EQUAL 
Unexpected T_IS_IDENTICAL 
Unexpected T_IS_NOT_EQUAL 
Unexpected T_IS_NOT_IDENTICAL 
Unexpected T_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL 
Unexpected `<` 
Unexpected `>`

Операторы сравнения, такие как `==`, `>=`, `===`, `!=`, `<>`, `!==` and `<=` or `<` and `>` в основном должны использоваться только в выражениях, таких как `if`. Если синтаксический анализатор жалуется на них, то это часто означает **несовпадение в парах скобок**, несоответствие скобок `(` `)` вокруг выражений.

1. #### Группировка в выражениях

   В частности, для операторов `if` с множественными сравнениями, вы должны позаботиться о правильном подсчете открывающих и закрывающих скобок (!!!):

   ```
                           ⇓
   if (($foo < 7) && $bar) > 5 || $baz < 9) { ... }
                         ↑
   ```

   Здесь условие `if` случайно завершено скобкой `)` и дальше парсер не понимает что происходит
2. #### Смешивание isset()/empty() и сравнения

   ```
                          ⇓  пропущена закрывающая скобка
   if (empty($_POST["var"] == 1)) {
   ```

   Или:

   ```
                      ⇓
   if (isset($variable !== "value")) {
   ```

   Это не имеет смысла для *PHP*, потому что `isset` и `empty` — языковые конструкции, которые принимают только имена переменных. Также не имеет смысла сравнивать результат этих конструкций с чем-либо, потому что результат этих конструкций - логический.
3. #### Путаница `>=` больше или равно с оператором массива `=>`

   Оба оператора выглядят примерно одинаково, поэтому их иногда путают:

   ```
            ⇓
   if ($var => 5) { ... }
   ```

   Нужно помнить, что этот оператор сравнения называется "*больше, чем* или *равно*" (greater than or equal), чтобы все было правильно.
4. #### Не с чем сравнивать

   Нельзя объединить два сравнения, если они относятся к одной и той же переменной:

   ```
                  ⇓
   if ($xyz > 5 && < 100)
   ```

   Необходимо каждый раз сравнивать значение переменной:

   ```
   if ($xyz > 5 && $xyz < 100)
   ```
5. #### Цепочки сравнения

   Также нельзя сравнивать значение переменной одновременно с несколькими значениями. В математике, например, конструкция ниже позволена:

   ```
                      ⇓
    $result = (5 < $x < 10);
   ```

   Однако в *PHP* такое не допустимо. Следует, как указано выше, сравнивать значение каждый раз, т.е.

   ```
    $result = ($x > 5 && $x < 10);
   ```
6. #### Unexpected `>` 
    Unexpected `<`

   Операторы больше `>` или меньше `<` не имеют пользовательского имени токенизатора `T_XXX`. Чаще всего ошибка возникает, когда не так расставлены кавычки в HTML коде:

   ```
                           ⇓
   print "<a href='z">Hello</a>";
                    ↑
   ```

   В текущем случае получается, что строка сравнивается через `>` с  константой `Hello` и затем происходит ещё одно сравнение с помощью `<`. По крайней мере, так это видит *PHP*. Настоящей причиной и синтаксической ошибкой было преждевременное завершение строки.

   Вложенные теги также вызывают ошибку::

   ```
   <?php echo <?php my_func(); ?>
              ↑
   ```

Answer (score 0):

##### Unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) 
Unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE) 
Unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED) 
Unexpected 'final' (T_FINAL)

Ключевые слова `public`/`private`/`protected`/`final` можно использовать **только внутри класса** в качестве модификатора для свойств или методов. Ключевое слово `final` может применяться ещё и для обозначения самого класса как финального.

Ошибка может заключаться в применении этих слов для простых функций **вне класса**, например

```
<?php 

public function echoTest() {    
    echo 'test';
}
```

Это **неправильно**! Нужно использовать только в классах!

Если же это происходит в классе, то смотрите на соответствия фигурных скобок закрывающих и открывающих - где-то может не хватать закрывающей фигурной скобки и в итоге парсер не ожидает увидеть ключевое слово.

Answer (score 0):

##### Unexpected T_STATIC

Может возникать в классе, когда используется позднее статическое связывание через ключевое слово `static`

```
class Employee {
    public static $favSport = "Football";

    public static function watchTV() {
        echo "Watching ".static::$favSport;
    }
}
```

Частой причиной может быть рання версия языка. Ключевое слово появилось в версии 5.3. Возможно у вас стоИт более ранняя версия.

Также если в классе `static` применяется в качестве возвращаемого значения:

```
 public function setDefault(string $option, mixed $value): static
```

Данное возвращаемое значение можно использовать в языке в версии 8.0+.  Проверьте свою версию *PHP*

---

---

##### Unexpected T_CLASS

Может возникать в классе, когда используется позднее статическое связывание через ключевое слово `[::class](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class)`

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
```

Частой причиной может быть рання версия языка. Ключевое слово появилось в версии 5.5. Возможно у вас стоИт более ранняя версия.

Ещё может быть случайно строка представлена константой. Пример:

```
$host=""MyHost"";
```

Тут ошибка заключается в том, что вместо того, чтобы написать одну двойнуй кавычку слева и одну справа, двойные кавычки написаны по две штуки. В итоге  получается слева пустая строка и справа, а `host` это какая-то константа, воспринимаемая как указание на какой-то класс

---

---

##### Unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

Может возникать в классе, когда используется ключевое слово `use` используется для импорта класса, но используется оно не **до объявления класса**/функции, а внутри него. Пример:

```
function test() {
    use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
    use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;
    
    ...
}
```

Все импорты классов должны быть в самом начале файла:

```
<?php 

use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;

class Test {
    function test() {       
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Исключение составляют [трейты](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.traits.php), которые **могут** использовать `use` внутри класса для импорта трейта (см. документацию)

---

Ещё проблема может возникать при использовании `use` для именованных функций. Это неверно! Оно может использоваться только для **анонимных функций**. Пример:

```
// НЕВЕРНО!!!
function checkValue($arrPostKey, $value) use ($errors) {
                                         ^^^^
    ...
};

// ВЕРНО
$checkValue = function($arrPostKey, $value) use (&$errors) {
    ...
}
```

---

Ещё одна проблема: в перечислении импортов сверху класса была забыта точка с запятой:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\Task   <-----
use App\Project;
```

---

---

##### Unexpected T_DNUMBER

Частая проблема: использовать данные как есть, вместо оборачивания их как строки. Пример:

```
// НЕВЕРНО
$this->Server = mysql3.000webhost.com;  // как итог: видим 3.000 ... на что и ругается парсер.

// ВЕРНО
$this->Server = 'mysql3.000webhost.com';
                ^---                  ^---
```