# Что не так с кодом)PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7

выдает ошибку

```
Parse error: 
syntax error, unexpected '$login' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')' 
in
D:\open_server\OSPanel\domains\gosti.com\handler.php on line 8
```

а вот и сам код:

```
        <?php

         include('includes/db.php');

         $login = $_POST['login'];
         $password = $_POST['password'];

         $count = mysqli_query($connection , "SELECT * FROM  `users`  WHERE `login` = "$login" AND  
         `
         password` = "$password"");
    
         if(mysqli_num_rows($count) == 0)
        {
           echo 'пользователь не найден';
        } else (){
             echo 'Привет . $login .';
        }
```

db.php:

```
        <?php

        $connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','username','','db') ;

        if( $connection == false )
        {
           echo 'CONNECTION IS CORRUPT<br>';
           echo mysqli_connect_error();
          exit();
       }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [PHP parse/syntax errors; Ошибки Unexpected XXX и как решить их](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1437802/php-parse-syntax-errors-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-unexpected-xxx-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%85)

Comment: @МихаилРебров есть же дубликат ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

```
// здесь и здесь не хватает конкатенации: ↓↓     ↓↓ 
 "SELECT * FROM  `users`  WHERE `login` = "$login" AND
```

Должно быть так

```
//            обратите внимание на точки: ↓↓      ↓↓ 
 "SELECT * FROM  `users`  WHERE `login` = ".$login." AND
```

Буквально следующая строка

```
 ` // ← вы открываете экранирующую кавычку.. переходите на другую строку
 password` = "$password"");
 //      ↑ и закрываете ее здесь
```

не надо так.

не отходя от кассы

```
 //          ↓↓       ↓↓ опять без конкатенации
 password` = "$password"");
 //               а тут ↑ поставьте хоть точку с запятой для приличия
```

как итог данное выражение выглядит так:

```
$count = mysqli_query($connection , "SELECT * FROM  `users`  WHERE `login` = ".$login." AND  
`password` = ".$password.";");
```

Далее

```
    // ↓↓ а это что?
} else (){
```

`else` не имеет условного выражения, зачем вам тут скобки?
Они вам не нужны тут - их нужно убрать.

Есть `elseif (выражение){ /*...*/ }`, но это другое выражение и оно не применимо в вашем случае

Поэтому скобки просто убираем

```
} else {
```

Дальше:

```
        // ↓↓         ↓↓ забыли закрыть строку кавычкой
echo 'Привет . $login .';
       //    ↑        ↑  зато конкатенация есть
```

Должно быть:

```
echo 'Привет '. $login .';';
```

#### В результате:

```
<?php
include('includes/db.php');

$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$count = mysqli_query($connection , "SELECT * FROM  `users`  WHERE `login` = ".$login." AND  
`password` = ".$password.";");

 if(mysqli_num_rows($count) == 0)
 {
     echo 'пользователь не найден';
 } elseif (true){
     echo 'Привет '. $login .';';
}
```