# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$data' (T_VARIABLE) in D:\server\OSPanel\domains\social\register.php on line 4

Tags: php

Я начинающий подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема и выскакивать эта ошибка?

```
 <?php 
require "db.php"

$data = $_POST;
if( isset($data['do_signup']) ) 
{
    $errors = array();
    if( trim($data['login']) == '' )
    {
        $errors[] = 'Введіть логін';
    }

    $errors = array();
    if( $data['password'] == '' )
    {
        $errors[] = 'Введіть пароль';
    }

    if( empty($errors))
    
    else`введите сюда код`
    {
        echo '<div style="red">'.array_shift($errors)'</div><hr>';
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Покажите полный текст ошибки и объясните, как должен работать код.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$data' (T_VARIABLE) in D:\server\OSPanel\domains\social\register.php on line 4     Вот текст ошибки. Код для реализации регистрации и авторизации, Проверка на заполнение полей.

Comment: Если вы хотите что-либо добавить к своему вопросу, не нужно писать это в комментариях. Дополнить вопрос можно нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Нет точки с запятой после `require "db.php"`

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [PHP parse/syntax errors; Ошибки Unexpected XXX и как решить их](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1437802/php-parse-syntax-errors-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-unexpected-xxx-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%85)