# Проблема с реализацией поиска. Как исправить ошибку?

Tags: php, mvc, search

Ошибка вроде бы и понятная, но как её исключить в моём случае — не соображу.

`Notice: Undefined index: termin in /application/models/AdminModel.php`

Контроллер:

```
public function postssearchAction($search = []) 
{   
    if ($_POST) {
        $search = $_POST['termin'];
    }

    $vars = [
        'search' => $this->model->postsSearch($this->route),
    ];
    $this->view->render('Результаты поиска', 0, 0, $vars, $search);
    
}
```

Модель:

```
public function postsSearch($route, $search = [])
{
    $params = [
        'termin' => $_POST['termin'],
    ];
    
    return $this->db->all('SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `title` LIKE :termin ORDER BY `id`', $params);
}
```

Comment: Модель, которая лезет в `$_POST` — это какая-то очень странная модель...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что означает эта ошибка? (parse, syntax, warning, fatal)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1364090/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-parse-syntax-warning-fatal)

Comment: А передать в `postsSearch` вторым аргументом поисковый запрос запрещает религия?

Comment: u_mulder, а как?