# PHP Не работают правильно страницы пользователей

Tags: php, mysql

у меня на сайте есть авторизация,регистрация я хочу сделать профили юзеров есть такой код:

```
    <?php
session_start(); 
require_once("config.php"); 
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {$id =$_GET['id']; }
else
{ exit("invalid");}
if (!preg_match("|^[\d]+$|", $id)) {
exit("<p>Неверный формат запроса! Проверьте URL</p>");
}
if (!empty($_SESSION['login']) and !empty($_SESSION['password']))
{
$login = $_SESSION['login'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password'",$db); 
$myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2); 
if (empty($myrow2['id']))
   {
    exit("Вход на эту страницу разрешен только зарегистрированным пользователям! Код ошибки: 0");
   }
   else {
    exit("Вход на эту страницу разрешен только зарегистрированным пользователям! Код ошибки: 1");
    }
}
$id = $_GET['id'];
$my = $_GET['login'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'",$db); 
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (empty($myrow['login'])) { exit("Пользователя не существует! Возможно он был удален.");}
?>
```

Он работает но только для владельца страницы (id 2) /profile.php?id=2 когда я пишу (id 1) /profile.php?id=1 выводится совсем не то что я хочу, а выводится Привет, Username! вместо Ты попал на страницу Username!

```
<?php
if ($myrow['login']) {
echo "Привет, Username!";
}
else {
    echo "Ты попал на страницу Username!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: значит что-то где-то не так....что и где - можно включив отображение ошибок и отладкой ...см. выше ↑↑↑

Comment: По правде говоря, весь ваш код не очень) `$_SESSION` - это переменная сервера, в ней достаточно будет хранить ID пользователя и проверять, есть ли значение ID в сессии для авторизации. `$id =$_GET['id'];` дублируется.. preg_match будет лишним ну и тд.. проверка методом `empty` не логична.. mysql_query устарел) даже боюсь предположить что пошло не так

Comment: Я знаю что мой код не очень, но мне нужна помощь

Comment: Добавьте в код `var_dump($myrow);` и посмотрите что выдает

Comment: @Jour что так всех тянет на va_dump? Надо по-взрослому)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я предполагаю что там будет `$myrow[0]['login']` но стоит убедится что переменная вообще что-то в себе содержит)
Я больше юзаю print_r)))

Comment: array(12) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(5) "zavsc" ["login"]=> string(5) "zavsc" [2]=> string(4) "test" ["password"]=> string(4) "test" [3]=> string(12) "Кирилл" ["name"]=> string(12) "Кирилл" [4]=> string(12) "Кирилл" ["surname"]=> string(12) "Кирилл" [5]=> string(1) "0" ["status"]=> string(1) "0" }

Comment: @zavsc `if ($myrow['id'] ==  $myrow2['id']) {` возможно так) + рекомендую заменить `mysql_fetch_array` на `mysql_fetch_assoc` не будет значений по индексам)

Comment: @zavsc ну вот сделай теперь вывод что ты сравниваешь в if и что на самом деле есть в переменной.....какой конкретно путь нужен......

Comment: @Jour Не работает, выводится Привет. Username!

Comment: @zavsc тогда последний вариант, воспользуйтесь рекомендацией от Алексея из первого сообщения.

Comment: @Jour PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: login in /profile.php on line 25 PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: myrow2 in /profile.php on line 53"

Comment: "Undefined index: login " --- посмотри внимательно на структуру своего массива и на то, как ты обращаешься по ключу....... опять же - используй отладку

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1364430/191482  - про undefined index