# Переадресация на файл php

Tags: php, html

У меня есть два файла: index.html и admin.php. В index.html я сделал ссылку на admin.php, но ссылка ведёт меня к показу кода файла admin.php, а мне нужно увидеть сам сайт admin.php, а не простой код.

```
<a id="login" href="admin.php">Войти</a>
```

Comment: в начале файла стоит `<?php` ?

Comment: локальный сервер стоИт?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1364091/191482

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, спасибо. Поставил локальный севрер. Напрочь забыл просто :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас не происходит обработка PHP на сервере. Разметка HTML выполняется внутри браузера, в свою очередь PHP код не может быть обработан браузером.

Попробуйте воспользоваться локальным сервером, например: Open Server или XAMPP.

В случае с Open Server, создайте в папке openserver/domains папку с названием сайта, в которой и храните различные файлы(html, css, php). Аналогично с XAMPP, XAMPP/htdocs

Запустите локальный сервер и перейдите на свой сайт по адресу http://ИмяСайта

Если явно не указывать конкретный файл, должен открываться index файл, через который потом можно производить редирект на другие страницы сайта.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Разобрался уже :)