# Выборка данных из БД firebird при помощи PHP + PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo, firebird

Есть БД FireBird, в ней есть строка с данными. Есть РНР+PDO код, который обрабатывает запрос выборки данных из таблицы БД FireBird, проблема в том, что все работает, но не выводит строку из таблицы. Помогите, очень нужно...

```
<?php

$dsn = 'firebird:dbname=/var/databases/test_db.fdb;charset=utf8;';
$username = 'SYSDBA';
$password = 'masterkey';

        try {
            $fire_conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
            
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

$curr_date = date('d.m.Y');

echo "<br> Список того, что купить " . $curr_date . " числа!" ;

$sql = "Select name_product, amount_product, price, cost from shopping
where date_buy = :date;";

$result = $fire_conn->prepare($sql);
$result ->bindParam(':date', $curr_date);
$result->execute();

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>
        <th>Название продукта</th>
        <th>Количество</th>
        <th>Цена</th>
        <th>Стоимость</th>
      </tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo "<tr><td>".$row['name_product']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['amount_product']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['price']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['cost']."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";



?>
```

Undefined array key "cost" in /var/www/html/StudyPHP/Result.php on line 37

К name_product amount_product price такая же ошибка

Пробовал погуглить, но что-то подобных тем не нашел...

Comment: Что показывает `print_r($row)`?

Comment: Вот за тебя погуглил - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1364090/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-parse-syntax-warning-fatal

Comment: в файле логов писало, что не знает столбцы name_product, amount_product, price, cost.
Исправил эту ошибку путем написание имен столбцов капсом, т.к. РНР чувствителен к регистру.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решена, именя столбцов нужно было написать так: $row['ИМЯ_СТОЛБЦА']