# Выдаёт ошибку Call to a member function fetch_assoc()

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc()
> on boolean in C:\OpenServer\domains\Diplom\php\checkdata.php:8 Stack
> trace: #0 {main} thrown in
> C:\OpenServer\domains\Diplom\php\checkdata.php on line 8

Не могу найти ошибку.

```
<?php
        $login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']),
         FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $pass = filter_var(trim($_POST['psw']),
         FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'diplom');
    $result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `pass` = '$pass'");
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if(count($user) == 0){
        echo "Такого пользователя нету";
        exit();
    }
    print_r($user);
    exit(); 
    $mysql->close();
    header('Location: /');
    ?>
```

Comment: Плюс https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482  до кучи

Comment: Можно ли конкретный ответ на мой вопрос?

Comment: Тут скорее https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole Ну и вбивать [сообщение об ошибке в поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Call+to+a+member+function+fetch_assoc%28%29) пока не запрещено.