# Не выводит 0 при ненахождении

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Не выводит 0 при ненахождении и невозможно выполнить условие при ненахождении

```
$result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(*) as `rates`
FROM users
WHERE Ckbr = {$cnv2}");

$results = array();

while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc())
 {
    $results[] = $row;
 }


 $numCnv = $results[0]['rates'];

 if($numCnv > $num0)
  {
  echo "больше нуля " .$numCnv;

   }
   else
    {
      echo "меньше нуля " .$numCnv;
     }
```

пытался так:

```
 if (empty($numCnv)) {
 echo 'или 0, или пусто, или вообще не определена';  
  }
```

Как решить проблему ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Так условие наверное должно быть `$numCnv > 0`, а не то что у Вас. Либо опишите что это за переменная такая `$num0`

Comment: $num0 значение этой переменной 0, сейчас попробую без переменной

Comment: Если там действительно 0, то это не поможет. Просто в Вашем примере который привден здесь, эта переменная нигде не определена. Смотрите что у Вас за значение в переменной `$numCnv`, из этого вытечет почему Ваш код не работает.

Comment: как его можно посмотреть?

Comment: Как смотреть ошибки и код - написано в самом первом комментарии по ссылке

Comment: вот что пишет Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Вызов функции-члена fetch_assoc() на bool в /home/u1390938/domains/123/public_html/9.php:23 Трассировка стека: #0 {main} брошено в /home/u1390938/domains/123/public_html/9.php on line 23

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/423439/191482   (вкратце - запрос неверный и вернул false)

Comment: if(isset($numCanvas) === false)
       {
       echo "ноль";

        }  или как проверить?

Answer (score 0):

Если тебя я правильно понял то тебе нужно вроде этого? :

```
<?php
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "12345", "test");
        if($conn->connect_error) die("Ошибка: " . $conn->connect_error);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    ?>
    
    <? if($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
        if ($result->num_rows) { ?>
            <h2>Список пользователей</h2>
            <p>Получено объектов: <?= $result->num_rows ?></p>
    
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Имя</th>
                </tr>
    
                <? foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $row["id"] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $row["login"] ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <? } $result->free(); ?>
            </table>    
    <? } else { 
        echo "Пусто!";
    
    } } $conn->close() ?>
```

Comment: спасибо, но код оказывается работает правильно, из за {$cnv2} не работал, но вчера работало, ни че не пойму, почему вчера работал с {$cnv2}  а сегодня нет, бред какой-то. Подскажите как лучше переменную указать вместо этого {$cnv2}

Comment: решил вопрос, тема закрыта, всем спс