# Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, PHP Warning

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, warning

Нужно настроить выгрузку API в БД, при компиляции выдаёт такую ошибку:

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in /srv/www/merlion/html/auvix/loadProducts.php on line 78

```
function endLoad($text) {
    $this->logger->write(sprintf('%s******************* Stop load *********************', PHP_EOL));
    $this->logger->write(sprintf('stop time: %s', date('d.m.Y H:i:s')));
    $this->logger->write(sprintf('cntAll = %s, cntAllToInsert = %s, cntProp = %s, cntImg = %s', $this->cntAll, $this->cntAllToInsert, $this->cntProp, $this->cntImg));
    
    $sql_available = "update auvix_products set available=0 where existinlastload=0";
    mysql_query($sql_available, $this->connection);
```

78 строка является последней в предоставленном отрезке кода, буду признателен за любую помощь.

Остальные API-шники работают, про блема лишь с этим кодом, хотя ничего в нём не менялось

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Comment: если это функция $this->connection не имеет смысла, если это метод класса, $this->connection нужно засетить существующим соединением в конструкторе этого класса

Comment: @abu в конце кода расписана эта переменная
`$logger = new Logger(sprintf('/srv/www/merlion/html/auvix/log/AuvixProductsToDB_%s.txt',date('Y_m_d')));
$si = new SimpleImage();
$connection = MerlionConnectionFactory::getConnection();
$t  = new AuvixProductsToDBLoader($logger, $si);
$t->loadProducts();`

Comment: если в исходном отписан метод класса `AuvixProductsToDBLoader`, то непонятно как свойство класса `connection` сетится из переменной `connection`. Стоит объявить в классе свойство (если еще не объявлено), а переменную передавать в конструктор и там насечивать в свойство