# Исползования параметра функции в качестве запроса на mysqli в php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Я использовал параметр функции в качестве запроса на mysqli

```
function checker($ip){
  $ipcheck = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `id` FROM IPes WHERE `ip` = '" . $_POST[$ip] . "'");
  //some code....
}
checker("ip");
```

но мне выдает ошибку ***mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given***
я убрал $_POST в функции пробовал сделать так

```
checker($_POST["ip"])
```

но нечего не изменилось, помогите пожалуйста я ещё новинький в php.

Comment: Откуда в Вашей функции берется переменная `$conn`?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Comment: $conn я использую include "cfg.php" с этим проблем нету

Comment: "с этим проблем нету" --- проблема как раз в этом и в тексте ошибки вполне указано на это

Comment: вам стоит ознакомиться с понятием "область видимости переменных"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается ответ был прост

```
function checker($ip){
  global $conn;
  $ipcheck = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `id` FROM IPes WHERE `ip` = '" . $_POST[$ip] . "'");
  //some code....
}
checker("ip");
```

сделать подключение глобальным

Comment: Использование глобальных переменных -- плохая практика.

Comment: Глобальные переменные могут сыграть с вами злую шутку, когда вы будете модифицировать код в будущем. Лучше просто сделать  $conn и $_POST['ip'] аргументами функции checker: `checker($conn, $_POST['ip']);`. Так же обратите внимание, что у вас тут [sql-инъекция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). Используйте [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)