# ошибка после отправки запроса в БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос

Понадобилось сделать много инпутов (больше 100) и присвоить им уникальные номера для работы с БД, суть проблемы такова, после отправки пост запроса с данными из инпутов вылетает ошибка которая ругается на запрос к БД (хотя запрос срабатывает и в базу все корректно записывается)

"Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in .... on line 17"

```
function select($query) {
    global $conn;
    $queryResult = [];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {        || line 17 ||
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $queryResult[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $queryResult;
}
```

и выдает ошибку на header()
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ... on line 84

```
case ($_POST['range'] != ''):
        if (isAdmin()){
            foreach ($_POST['range'] as $key => $value) {
                $range_update = "UPDATE warehouse SET range".$key[0]."='$value' WHERE id =".$key[2].$key[3];
                $ranges = select($range_update);
            }
            header("Location: /warehouse/".$route[1]);    || line 84||
            break;
        }
```

а так выглядит инпут который делает отправку через POST.
в name массиве у инпута 0 элемент 1-8, а 1 элемент 1-64. поэтому соорудил такого монстра (если вдруг вопрос образуется)

```
$out .= "<td><input name=range[1,".$warehouse_out[$i]['id']."] class='wirehouse' type='text' placeholder=".$warehouse_out[$i]['range1']."></td>";
```

Comment: после
$range_update = "UPDATE warehouse SET range".$key[0]."='$value' WHERE id =".$key[2].$key[3];
напишите print_r($range_update);exit;
посмотрите что выведет, если ошибки в запросе нет, то запустите его в PMA или через консоль

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [mysqli_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php) возвращает количество строк только при операциях `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE`, или `EXPLAIN`. В остальном случае он возвращает TRUE или FALSE в зависимости выполнился запрос или нет.

Далее передаете это в функцию `mysqli_num_rows()`, который и говорит что получил булево значение вместо результата/таблицы. Как вариант, используйте [mysqli_affected_rows()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) вместо нее, которая возвращает количество затронутых строк с самого последнего выполненного запроса на `$conn`:

```
if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: много часов искал косяк в своем коде, а оказалось что просто нехватка знаний. Спасибо!