# Помогите найти ошибку в скрипте регистрации

Tags: php, html, mysql

Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку(-и) в скрипте для регистрации пользователей. Перед тем как задать вопрос, ознакомился с ответами вот здесь [Клик!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/353257/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-mysql-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given)

Название БД prog, содержит 3 поля id, login, password

Вот php скрипт:

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'prog');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['username']));
    $password1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['password1']));
    $password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['password2']));
    if (!empty($username) && !empty($password1) && !empty($password2) && ($password1 == $password2)) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE login = '$username'";
        $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO 'users' (login, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password1')";
            mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            echo 'Все готово, можете войти';
            mysqli_close($dbc);
            exit();
        }
        else{
            echo "Логин уже существует";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

А это html разметка:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
            <lable for="username">Введите логин</lable>
            <input type="text" name="username">
            <lable for="password1">Введите пароль</lable>
            <input type="password" name="password1">
            <lable for="password2">Пароль ещё раз</lable>
            <input type="password" name="password2">
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Регистрация</button>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

В браузере выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\OpenServer\domains\mysql.test\script\reg.php on line 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE login = '$username'";
```

Вот так вот. название таблиц нужно заклюать в апострофы(`), а не в одинарные кавычки (')

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! 3 часа сидел искал в чем проблема, от ответа аж смешно стало, банальная невнимательность

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'prog');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $dbc->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));
    $password1 = $dbc->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password1']));
    $password2 = $dbc->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password2']));
    if (!empty($username) && !empty($password1) && !empty($password2) && ($password1 == $password2)) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE login = '$username'";
        $data = $dbc->query($query);
        if ($dbc->num_rows == 0) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (login, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password1')";
            $dbc->query($query);
            echo 'Все готово, можете войти';
            $dbc->close($dbc);
            exit();
        }
        else{
            echo "Логин уже существует";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

> Используйте ООП , так все проще и яснее

Comment: Как изучу mysql, буду учить ООП. Спасибо за совет!